# What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?

Tags: support, faq, downvotes, serial-voting, abuse

I just got a flood of irrational downvotes on a bunch of my posts in a short period of time. I suspect they may have been targeted at me based on a disagreement with another user rather than due to the quality of my posts.

Is there anything that I can do regarding this flood of downvotes?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Don't worry. [There is a system in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) which will pick this issue up (at 3 am UTC) and will reverse it. There is nothing you need to do.

The automatic serial vote script should pick this up, but if in the unlikely event it doesn't clear them all, **wait 24 hours** and should any suspicious downvotes remain, flag one of the posts for moderator attention using the "in need of moderator intervention " option and explain what happened.

The moderator team will take a look and if it is the case that the script missed any they'll talk to the community team and see if we can get them reversed manually.

#### See also: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: Extension: mods have to fulfill strong privacy requirements. For example, if they suspended the perpetrator, they can't say it to you. Know it, and don't expect too much information what they did. Don't worry even if your flags are declined. **Just flag.**

Comment: I feel like I have to ask for permission to ask, but why would somebody do that?

Comment: @user56983 probably if A and B are in an edit war, B might downvote A's posts so A loses the edit privilege

Comment: What period is considered in automatic script to detect revenge downvoting ? One Day, one Week, one Month ? Since I have spoken on Meta, every 2 days, an unkown user will downvote some of my post. Normally I have a downvote every month.

Comment: @schlebe See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308502/stealth-revenge-downvoter-a-downvote-a-day-keeps-the-reversal-script-away As that appears to constitute enough of a pattern, consider flagging one of your posts for moderator attention describing the situation in detail. Then if there really is something mischievous, all you have to do is wait.