# Mechanism to detect or validate spite-downvotes?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

I've stumbled upon two of my unanswered posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160792/does-osg-contain-a-geometry-split-visitor

[LNK2005 (already defined) – Linker behaves strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885275/lnk2005-already-defined-linker-behaves-strange)

which received downvotes in the last seven days without any comment on what was wrong. Now that the possibility to get an answer is basically zero I was wondering whether this is just a spite downvote or whether there is a way to detect such a behaviour?

(While I am of course curious who has done that I asked my self whether there is a system that correlates a users behaviour against a user and the history with that user,e.g. a preceeding downvote, etc to prevent such a user just spamming down-votes)

Comment: No, the intent of *individual* votes cannot be auto-detected. We have yet to invent over-the-internet brainscanning tech to do so. *Serial* voting (one user upvoting or downvoting a series of posts by another user in a short timespan) *is* detected and auto-reversed.

Comment: Also see [Just got a flood of downvotes. What can I do about it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252270) and [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was not thinking about brainscanning but on correlation of user-to-user interaction. If user B made a comment on a topic of user A and user A started to down-vote user B's questions in a given period of time might indicate such a behaviour.

Comment: And at the same time the interaction may have triggered a closer look at the questions and the downvotes were given because the user thought the questions deserved to be downvoted. You cannot assume the votes were done out of spite.

Comment: Just because there was no comment doesn't mean that the votes were out of spite.  The voter may well have sincerely felt that the questions weren't quality questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, but how could this be detected? Let's think of all the reasons someone may want to downvote you:

- You downvoted them
- You rejected an edit of theirs
- You flagged or closed their post
- You said something they disagreed with in a question, answer, comment or chat message
- A guy called Samuel looked at them funny once and you reminded them of it

But is any of that suspicious? Not really, especially not on the smaller SE sites and those in beta, chances are any users who has been there a while has probably voted or responded to or seen a post written by everyone else. There's just no way to know.

Comment: You left out the #1 reason I downvote posts: the question or answer is low quality.

Comment: Or when a user clicks on the wrong vote arrow by accident (I guess it's a very small percentage, but a possibility nonetheless)