# Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?

Tags: support, faq, reputation, profile-page, reputation-history

I know that I gain and lose reputation when people vote on my posts. For example, when one of my answers receives an upvote, I earn 10 points and receive a green notification in the top bar.

However, sometimes I see my reputation score increase or decrease without any reason given in my profile. Is this a bug?

How can I understand the reason(s) why I gained or lost reputation?

Is there any way that I can audit my entire reputation history?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Very related: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 356, accepted):

## How do I gain or lose reputation?

Users gain or lose reputation based on the quality of their interactions with the system and other community members. The primary reason for reputation change is voting. Posts which are voted up increase their authors reputation; the reverse is true for posts which are voted down. Upvotes are more heavily weighted than downvotes. (Posts which have Community Wiki status are exceptions to the reputation rules; they do not affect their authors' or editors' reputations.)

#### You gain reputation when:

- one of your posts is voted *up*: **+10**
- one of your answers is *accepted*: **+15**
- you *accept* an answer written by someone else to one of your own questions: **+2**
- someone removes their downvote on one of your questions or answers: **+2**
- you suggest an edit and it is approved: **+2** (up to a total of +1000 per user)
- you remove a downvote from an answer *or* an answer you downvoted is deleted: **+1**
- one of your answers is awarded a bounty by the user offering the bounty: **+full bounty amount**
- one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: **+½ of the bounty amount**
- you *associate accounts* between two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: **+100** on each site (awarded a maximum of once per site)

#### You lose reputation when:

- one of your questions or answers is voted *down*: **−2**
- a post where you had successfully *suggested an edit* has been *deleted* (reputation page shows the cause as "*removed*"): **-2**

  - (if you didn't earn reputation from the edit because you had hit the daily reputation cap or the overall cap from approved suggested edits, you won't lose anything)
- you vote an answer *down* (downvotes on questions are free): **−1**
- an upvote on one of your questions is removed: **−10**
- an upvote on one of your answers is removed: **−10**
- one of your formerly accepted answers loses *accepted* status: **−15**
- you *unaccept* an answer written by someone else to one of your own questions: **-2**
- you place a bounty on a question: **−full bounty amount**
- one of your posts receives six "spam" or "rude or abusive" flags (formerly known as "offensive" flags): **−100**

#### Additionally:

- All users start with one reputation point.
- No user's reputation may drop below one.
- You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given [day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start). Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately. Earned, uncounted reputation does not "roll over" to the next day.
- Accepting your own answer does not gain you any reputation.
- [Reversal of voting fraud](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes) will return lost or gained reputation.

See also: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) in the Help Center

---

## How do I audit changes to my reputation?

First, open your user profile page (by clicking your user card in the center of the top bar). Then, click on the "reputation" tab:

[image]

Or, you can visit the URL directly:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/your-user-id/?tab=reputation
```

Or, you can view it directly if you are signed in by using [`current` as the user id](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=reputation).

On this page, you can choose between "post", "time", and "graph" views of your reputation history.

#### What are all the event types and what do they mean?

- **upvote**/**downvote** — Your post was upvoted or downvoted.
- **unupvote**/**undownvote** — An upvote or downvote previously cast on the post was retracted.
- **downvoted** (note the extra "d" at the end) — you *cast* a downvote on an answer. Downvotes you cast on questions do not affect your reputation and are not shown in your reputation history.
- **accept**/**unaccept** — Your answer was accepted or unaccepted by the person who asked the question, or you accepted an answer on one of your questions.
- **bounty** — You offered a bounty on a question or a bounty was awarded on your answer.
- **removed** — Usually indicates the post was deleted (this could be any post you *took action on*, not necessarily a post you owned). Keep in mind that when a question is deleted, all of its answers are automatically deleted as well. This event is also used when a [user is removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470).

  - (When a post is deleted, its title is shown as plain text to those who don't have privileges to view it.)*
- **migrated** — Your post was migrated to another site.
- **edit** — An edit you suggested to a post or tag wiki was approved.
- **reversal** — Another user [serially voted on your posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829), which got reversed.

#### Why is there an unexpected or no reputation change next to the event?

Most often it's due to you hitting the reputation cap. You can only earn up to 200 reputation from votes and edits in a single day. Sometimes the last event that puts you up to the limit will be slightly less than what you'd normally find, such as a +6 for an upvote to your answer. After hitting the cap, all additional events will show no reputation change.

Additionally, any upvotes you get to community wiki questions or answers you have will still show up in the reputation history, but will not show any reputation change next to them since they are not eligible for reputation gain.

Events in your reputation history are also wrapped up into a single line when they occur on the same day. If you are viewing your history by time, this can cause some confusion as it might appear that you have received additional reputation for a new upvote that just occurred, when in fact you didn't. See:

[image: This example shows 70 points gained for upvotes at 18:34.]

This is because that single post will be listed by the time of the *last* event on your post with the sum of *all* events on that post, even if you didn't gain any additional reputation for that event. If you find this confusing, try switching your reputation history view to the "post" option. This will allow you to expand each post to see all the separate events for it, including how many gained you reputation and how many didn't.

[image: View history by post.]

#### My reputation went down, but I don't see anything listed!

This can be caused by one of several different reasons:

- **Removed posts are hidden.** More than likely, you don't have your reputation history set to show removed posts. By default, removed posts are hidden from the history pages. In order to show removed posts, you need to make sure to check the "show removed posts" checkbox all the way at the bottom:
  [image]

  You can also check your [Deleted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current) or [Deleted Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/current) directly with these links.
- **Reversal events from the same day.** When you receive an upvote and a subsequent unupvote event (or an accept and an unaccept, or a downvote and an undownvote) from the same user on the same day, the events collapse into each other and are not displayed in your reputation history. This was primarily done to prevent users from spamming a user's reputation history with consistent events reversing each other. A reversed event (unupvote, undownvote, unaccept) will only appear if it occurs on a day other than the day the original event occurred.
- **Background processes.** If you're still unable to see what caused a sudden reputation drop, there may have been a system process in the background. This usually happens when a post that affected your reputation in some way was deleted or undeleted, or two or more accounts are merged together.

#### Why would an event disappear from my reputation history?

This *should* only occur for upvotes, downvotes, and accepts. Whenever one of these actions gets reversed during the same day, the event is just completely removed from your history rather than creating a separate unupvote, undownvote, or unaccept event in the list. This was done to prevent users clicking a vote on/off repeatedly to fill up a user's history with useless events.

---

## That's too fancy—how do I get the *real* scoop?

Make sure you are logged in, and visit this page: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

This will give you a plain-text file that details changes to your reputation over time.

The **first number** is the [vote type](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types), where common vote types are:

- 1 = accepted answer (to or from you)
- 2 = upvote (to you)
- 3 = downvote (to or from you)
- 4 = penalty for post flagged as offensive
- 8 = bounty grant (from you)
- 9 = bounty award (to you)
- 12 = penalty for post flagged as spam
- 16 = edit suggestion approved

The **second number** is the post ID that the vote was on. Remember that votes on community wiki posts do *not* generate rep, so those votes will not appear here. (Note that some vote types like offensive, spam, and bounties apply to any post regardless of its community wiki status.)

The **third number** is the value of the vote. Note that the value may be capped if you reach the daily upvote reputation limit. If the value is capped, it will appear in brackets like `[3]` so.

The **date boundaries** are printed whenever your reputation changed in a given day(s). It contains the current date, the amount your rep changed (up or down) since the last time, and the total amount of rep you have earned to date.

---

<sup>(Originally adapted and slightly simplified from the following FAQ entries on the global Meta: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation), and [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation))</sup>