# lost 100+ reputation, how do you trace that?

Tags: support

I reached just over 2000 points yesterday  and received a notification about the 2000 milestone
[image]

for an increase in privilege - which is one of the reasons 2000+ was noteworthy.

At somewhere between 02:00 & 03:55 2014-08-29 I lost over 100 points, for no apparent reason and went back to 1911.

Is such a dramatic loss normal? Can it actually be traced?

According to the answers here [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history) a trace is available via:

https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

But the details there do not have the full history, which, if it was a full trace, would display the losses, which is doesn't.

2014-08-27 was about the same level as 2014-08-28 but the negatives of over 100 points aren't shown.

relevant portion of trace:

```
-- 2014-08-27 rep +54   = 1720      
 2  25539653 (10)
 2  25539653 (10)
 2  25539653 (10)
 1  25521688 (15)
 16 25543439 (2)
 2  25549368 (10)
 2  25549368 (10)
 2  25549368 (10)
 1  25549368 (15)
 2  25547471 (10)
 2  25546974 (10)
 2  25377078 (10)
 2  25422440 (10)
 1  25547471 (15)
 2  25559108 (10)
 1  25559108 (15)
-- 2014-08-28 rep +172  = 1892      
 2  25559769 (10)
 2  25559769 (10)
 3  25560790 (-1)
-- 2014-08-29 rep +19   = 1911      

** rep today: 19
** rep this week (2014-08-24 - 2014-08-30): 304
** rep this month (2014-08-01 - 2014-08-31): 1028
** rep this quarter (2014-07-01 - 2014-09-30): 1521
** rep this year (2014-01-01 - 2014-12-31): 1521
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 1911 :)

days represented 52
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days
earned 10 reputation from suggested edits
```

The only unusual event of today was I placed 2 comments on an answer (on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560588/sql-retrieve-distinct-rows-by-the-version-number)) , and that answer was then deleted. Do I get a punishment for that?

Comment: The checkbox 'show deleted posts' on the bottom of the reputation tab in the profile may be of use.

Comment: I tried that, didn't make any difference that I could see (and it would have to be more than 1 items to be over 100 points wouldn't it?) I'll try again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed think I have found it...

Comment: What sock account name did you use?  Already_Used_By_Already?

Comment: My display name was Used_By_Already at the time; why? I didn't alter my Display Name here yesterday (but I did at http://dba.stackexchange.com/ because it was USERnnnnn)

Comment: for the downvoter(s): I did research but didn't find the relevant answer because I wasn't sure how much I had lost. If I had realized it was 150 points I might have found it and not asked (note there is a lot of material to sift through on lost reputation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got 150 points subtracted from a serial upvote reversal today:

[image: screen shot]

You can find this in the reputation tab of your profile. Here is the help page explaining why and how this can happen:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: YES, just found it. maybe when I visited the trace file it wasn't updated with that yet... thank you