# Why are only 3 out of 5 (6) serial downvotes restored?

Tags: support, serial-voting

Yesterday evening I made a comment on some questions. A few minutes later 5 downvotes came within 2 minutes. And another one 30 minutes later. All on some of my "top" answers. So - a person turning to my profile and click click click downvoting 6 times.

Tonight, 3 (6 reputation) votes got restored.

Why just three?

Comment: I had a similar issue once. I flagged one of the downvoted posts for moderator attention and explained the situation. Later on, the other serial downvotes were reverted.

Comment: See the 2nd paragraph in the answer on the duplicate.

Comment: Probably three accounts involved, two that know each other.  Flag a mod so he can elevate it to CM.

Comment: It is a program, not a human.

Comment: I was watching this specific case, because you weren't the only one they targeted. I warned the user responsible, and they recognize the error in doing this. I was hoping the system would catch all these, because they clearly were from the same person, and it caught all the votes cast to others. Don't know why it missed yours, so I've escalated this to the CM team to review.

Comment: I am very relieved to hear that. The only thing that sucks more than revenge downvotes are revenge downvotes that stick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script to revert downvotes is "conservative". It does not invalidate votes lightly. One possible scenario is that the downvoter downvoted from several accounts, with only one account giving enough evidence.

So my guess is, there were two accounts downvoting - not necessarily belonging to the same user. The first account did 3 downvotes and triggered the reversal script. The second account did 2 downvotes, and did not trigger the reversal script.

If you believe that some serial voting was not undone as it should be, flag one of the affected posts for moderator attention, and explain the situation.

Comment: Automated processes are doomed to disappoint regularly :)

Comment: @Gimby We notice when it goes wrong, not when it goes right.

Comment: [Sometimes people do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270141/1663383) ;)