# Reputation points keep on vanishing?

Tags: bug

I have observed it many times. Reputation points go down by 3 or 4 points without leaving any trace under reputations changes.

Why does it happen? I have faced it many times.

Recently it happened again. Yesterday, my reputation points went down by 4. It was 2203 and now today it is 2199.

Comment: At the bottom of your reputation history there is a checkbox "show removed posts". Did you enable that?

Comment: @Bart thnx now atleast I can see whats happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely a question or answer where you earned +2 points for an edit was deleted, or another user account was deleted removing all of their votes.

See [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history/269654#269654) for the complete list.