# Many questions deleted overnight at exactly the same time

Tags: support, deleted-questions

A few questions I answered to and got upvotes for have been deleted overnight at exactly the same hour and minute.

Has there been any general deletion done that would have deleted a considerate amount of questions?

Here are links to those questions (only visible to 10k+ users - thanks @MartijnPieters):

- [adding a form in my validate, and it will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106114/adding-a-form-in-my-validate-and-it-will-not-work)
- [Add an li-Element with the actual post-title in wordpress-menu and set it as active, when site isnt al link of the menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106896/add-an-li-element-with-the-actual-post-title-in-wordpress-menu-and-set-it-as-act)
- [According to the php documentation, when I use var_dump($_REQUEST), I should not be able to get the elements, but I do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112972/according-to-the-php-documentation-when-i-use-var-dump-request-i-should-not)
- [Open/Close menus manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113110/open-close-menus-manually)

Comment: It'd help if you included links to those answers; 10k+ users can view the deleted posts still.

Comment: I just added the titles, don't have links obviously as I cannot reach them...

Comment: You can still right-click the links and copy them here.

Comment: See, those are suggested edits..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know perfectly how to copy a link :) but they're not linked in my profile, so thanks for adding them.

Comment: They would have been linked if these were actually your answers that were deleted. But these were not, instead they were questions you had suggested edits on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you know about a FAQ question or other post that would be about how to make these "removed" entries be more specific?

Comment: [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653) springs to mind.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for that, though it merely lists the reasons why reputation would decrease, doesn't discuss the lack of info on _removed_ reasons (ie. if I answered or just edited that question for example). I'll look out for other similar questions and may post another one if it makes sense... thanks for all your help!

Comment: The only 'post removed' reason that isn't linked is when you gained rep for a post that is not your own. And that is only when you suggested edits. The `-2` per post would have been a hint there as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your case, all 4 of the posts were questions you *suggested edits on* (you didn't lose answers), but were later deleted due to a negative score and having no answers with a positive score.

See [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> 8. The system will automatically delete [unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

(2 had answers, but those were self-deleted shortly after posting).

All 4 posts were without answer by September 30th and were deleted by a batch process. Do check out the linked FAQ for other ways the system will automatically delete posts; many of those reasons would be processed in batches.

Comment: just wondering, how realistic is it that 4 users are deleted at the same time? is it maybe just a coincidence?

Comment: @webeno: all 4 posts were 30 days old since their last downvote.