# My reputation has decreased

Tags: discussion, support, bug, reputation, reputation-history

When I check [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1800337/kushan-randima) few days ago, my reputation was over 60 (I guess it was 61). But now my reputation is 57 only. I checked “reputation” and “summary” tabs in my profile page. But I can’t see any record for the deduction. According to my knowledge, I didn’t get any notification either. How this has happened. Please explain me. Is this a bug?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history/269654#269654, scroll to the "My reputation went down, but I don't see anything listed!" heading.

Comment: Yeah me, too and it sucks. i desperately need to ask a question about javascript but none of my answers are getting votes, so i can't ask a question.

Comment: It's very painful

Answer (score 9):

Two of the posts you edited could be removed; check "show removed posts" in the bottom of your reputation tab. You don't get notifications in the dropdown when posts are removed causing rep changes.

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any idea about why someone has down-voted this question?? Do U see anything wrong here or any areas to be improved? Please let me know if there any. It will help to improve my self.

Comment: The downvote is probably becauses it is a duplicate.  This question is asked a lot of times in several ways, hence the generic question with enough answers.