# Sudden score drop without any notification of the reason

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

More than a year ago I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292880/create-sqlite-database-and-table/15292958#15292958) a question on how to create and use an sqllite version 3 database.

I did explain how to create and use this database from a C# point of view (what the questioner asked for). On top of that I added how to use it, using SQLLiteTransactions. There was a lot of effort put into that answer.

Not only was my answer marked as 'The answer' (which I believe helped the questioner), it was upvoted by 50+ others. So in that way I believe it was a helpful answer for the community too.

The other day I looked at my Stackoverflow account. My reputation score dropped significantly. There was no notification at all, telling me that the question along with my answer has been deleted. So no reason either.

Despite the fact that I lost reputation points, why didn't I get a notification that this happend and had to find out myself? And why is it possible for an answer with a decent number of upvotes to be deleted? I sometimes used my own answer for reference material.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The community voted to delete that post. Stack Exchange only posts notifications for *achievements*, which a deleted answer is not. You didn't lose any reputation, as the post was visible over 60 days and had a score over 3. The question was terrible, it really did not deserve to stick around.

Comment: Well, that's a great answer to a _terrible question_.  Hopefully someone active in the `[C#]` tag can comment.

Comment: It might be that you weren't notified because it was the question, and not your answer, that was deleted (the deletion of your answer was a side-effect), but I would call this a bug. I'm also curious about what the best course of action is when there's a useful answer to a really lousy question.

Comment: If you lost reputation, then that was probably for a different reason. See [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653)

Comment: @JLRishe: no, there is no bug here. See [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653) as to how to make deleted content visible in your reputation log.

Comment: I voted to undelete - the question has almost 29k views and the fact that your answer was upvoted 50+ times is a strong indicator that the question is _helping the Internet_, even though the OP did a poor job of asking it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: if undeleted, can people **please** knock that question into some semblance of shape then? As it stands it is one honking big broken window.

Comment: @JLRishe: we can undelete the post, but it really needs to be edited into a proper question. 10k+ users can do so before it is undeleted. That question is really terrible.

Comment: "My reputation score dropped significantly" - how significantly?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It probably can't be made any less broad, but it can be at least stated a little more comprehensibly. I'll take a first crack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's one very low quality question (titled "Create SQLite Database and table").

Reproduced in its entirety here:

> I wanted to create database and table using C#.
>
> By clicking submit button create ten database with fields.

---

It was **rightfully** deleted, and with it your answer was deleted and you lost the reputation.

You can think of this as a learning experience - if you are going to answer such a low quality question, perhaps **improve** it beforehand?

Comment: Yep, it's a really bad question. It couldn't get much worse. But it has tens of thousands of views and the answer is highly upvoted, so it's clearly helping people out there.

Comment: @Michael - it was deleted by 5 members of the community. 5 undelete votes will bring it right back.

Comment: The answer was [> 60 days visible and had a score of 3 or higher](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), so the OP should not have lost reputation here. Did they anyway?

Comment: It is hard to ask the questioner for more information, since he hasn't been online for a while when checking his Stackoverflow account.

Comment: @Max - sure, but the danger of answering such a bad question before cleanup/clarification is that it (and associated answers) will get deleted.

Comment: There still exists the option of improving the question now to help with the undelete effort and prevent it from getting deleted again, right?

Comment: @Oded I'm now aware of that. But the question survived more than a year on Stackoverflow and the answer has been improved along the way. In the end it is an helpful answer if someone Googles for 'How to create an SQLite database'. So I think it is strange that it wasn't deleted the first hours or days it got created.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - possibly could happen for _votes_ that are under 60 days, not sure. If that's the cause of the rep loss, it would be a bug. I am investigating.

Comment: @Max: the *question* hasn't been improved. There have been no edits to that question since the grace period expired 5 minutes after it was created.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I ment answer changed along the way. I edited the comment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I am not seeing rep loss due to that answer being removed. Nor am I seeing anything I would class as "sudden and significant loss of rep".

Comment: @Max there are enough users with the privilege (rep > 3K)  to close vote questions but unfortunately not all users actually use that privilege hence the large [close vote queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/). In high traffic tags like [tag:c#] some crap stays behind...

Comment: @Oded: I can only think that the OP experienced a drop in their [tag:c#] score and confused that with a reputation drop.