# Why didn't I get back my reputation after I deleted my downvoted answer?

Tags: support, downvotes, deleted-answers

Yesterday I deleted an answer with 2 downvotes, but it seems that I didn't get back my last reputation. I started with a score of 346 and now I have 341, after I got some down votes, but I removed the answer.

The sum of all reputation of my profile is still 346, but it shows 341. What is happening here?

My deleted answers are:

- [What's the right HTTP Status code for a blocked, abusive user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878039)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766132
- [Using PHP to convert tabs to spaces for HTML display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308168)

Comment: What was the answer you deleted? 10k+ users can still see it, we can then tell you what might be going on. The answer most likely had upvotes too, or had a final score over 3 and was at least 60 days old (in which case reputation is not removed).

Comment: Adding up your publicly visible reputation log events, I come to 341 points. You never downvoted anything according to your profile summary, so that'd be spot on.

Comment: I think the sum its not ok, but maybe its my problem I dont understand the reputation tab in my profile. thanks

Comment: The three answers only ever received downvotes, you'd have 329 points if you left those posts undeleted.

Comment: You can get a (rather technical) audit log at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation. Further see [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653)

Comment: With the link of @MartijnPieters its clear now. thanks

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I am facing the same issue as mentioned in this question. However in my case I checked above reputation URL and total votes show 1249. But my profile shows 1247 even after deleting answer with downvote(Deleted more than 20 min ago). Should I be creating another question or is it because the system is slow today?

Comment: @adev you are at 1249 now. 20 minutes isn’t enough time for the recalc to have taken place yet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks. I didn't know about that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just reproduced this, the link to my deleted answer is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69822404/8740349

Comment: @Top-Master you posted your comment less than 20 minutes after deleting that answer. Recalculations don’t take place instantly, you needed to wait longer, I can see you got your -2 reverted.