# Does -1 reputation from downvoting disappear if the answer is deleted?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes

A -1 for downvoting mysteriously disappeared from my rep history, and I can only assume it's because the answer was deleted.

While this makes a certain amount of sense, it's also not explicitly mentioned in the Help Center that I could find, or in questions on the meta that I searched (though mentioned in comments in some meta discussions).

Is this effect detailed somewhere?

Feature Request:
Would it be useful to include a note on the voting section of the Help Center (either on [Privileges > Vote Down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) or [What is Reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)) that reputation losses from downvoting an answer may be reverted if the answer is deleted?  This could encourage downvoting truly poor answers despite the reputation hit (especially among low-rep users) if they're aware of the possibility of getting the point back.

Comment: If you think it would be useful, you can also put in a feature request tag to your question.  I think it would be helpful information.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/266735) on the MSE FAQ seems to mention the reputation changes are reversed for an answer. You'll have to scroll down to the "What else should I know" section to find it. I was mildly surprised this information wasn't on the "Deleted Answer" help page (as it does have a "What happens when.." section), but that did link to the FAQ over on MSE. Edit: After further searching, that's the only "official" spot I can find it mentioned. Very odd they don't have it better documented.

Comment: Good point on the (lack of) documentation. At least I couldn't find it either after a few minutes of searching. But that's indeed how it works. You get the rep back when answers are deleted. And yes, that's why downvoting answers barely costs any rep. If you downvote truly bad answers, they will typically be deleted anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @ryanyuyu.  I agree and have edited the post per your suggestion.

Comment: Several help center articles on deletion do link to the community FAQ page on the subject: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) That page *does* go into (excruciating) detail about what effects deletion has on reputation.

Comment: reputation page would better refer readers to [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653/839601) which covers this and many other things that happen over there. That said, yeah, I observe 5-10 rep refunds from deleted downvoted answers a day average. @MartijnPieters high-five

Comment: @MartijnPieters I originally checked the reputation help pages, and afterward had to guess at the cause, because in my history I could no longer see the -1.  Checking FAQ pages on probable causes to see whether they mention the effect is a very indirect way to figure out what happened.  At first, I thought maybe a moderator had some special power to reverse the -1!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Yes, when an answer that you downvoted is deleted the reputation is refunded (and the vote too if on the same voting day).

When you show removed posts (at the bottom of your reputation page you will see a check box:[image]) in your reputation history you will see something like:

[image: down votes and deleted down votes]

Comment: What about when you remove a question? Personally, I think it's completely ridiculous to downvote a question. It makes sense for answers since answers can be wrong or unhelpful, but was my question wrong? Was my question not helpful to you? Did I inconvenience you by asking it?

Comment: @MathMachine there is a possibility that the question being asked doesn't show any effort from the OP... Or the OP is not interested in learning, rather they just want quick answers to complete their homework.

Comment: @Nothingspecial, even though that's a fair point but without informing where the OP can improve the question or where they can perhaps seek more information and answer their question, downvoting alone seems quite unhelpful. I had asked a question in stackoverflow and my question was getting downvoted. I was completely lost and confused. And I didn't know why until a person informed me he downvoted my question because I should have posted the question in SuperUser or Unix & Linux.