# If I delete my own answer, how will that affect my reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers

I have just spent 30 minutes looking over ten or fifteen different posts here on Meta Stack Overflow.

I searched for "Delete Answer Reputation" in various combinations and as part of differently phrased questions.

The closest answer I found was: This description, ["*What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) In that description, I don't see anything about reputation changes.

I also found This description, ["*Does -1 reputation from downvoting disappear if the answer is deleted?*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288285/does-1-reputation-from-downvoting-disappear-if-the-answer-is-deleted) but it just barely missed my question.

Anyway, one of my answers has been down-voted twice, so if I'm harming the community so badly, I want to correct my dangerous behavior.

The original question was also put on hold by five votes.

For reference,  [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175555/teaching-assembly-choosing-os-and-skipping-real-mode-x32/29179116#29179116) is where it's happening.

If I delete my answer, will it affect my reputation ?

Comment: Also note that if the answer is older than 60 days and has a score of +3 or higher, your rep from that answer will be retained forever.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> If I delete my answer, will it affect my reputation ?

Yes, you'll gain back the rep lost from the downvotes, and lose the rep from any upvotes.

Well, if you don't do that frequently it might not do any harm deleting your downvoted answers (as I have experienced at least).

If you have a lot of downvoted answers and just try to get rid of them by deletion, that won't help to preserve you from an answer ban.

---

> *"I want to correct my dangerous behavior."*

The point is, that it's sometimes *dangerous* to answer off-topic questions in the way they'd demanded to be answered (e.g. like *"give me links"*, *"gimme teh codez"*, or something alike). You usually just don't answer.

Well, I've seen high rep members providing answers for such questions, still. And these were upvoted a lot.

In the end if the question is decided being not worth answering by the community or engine, it will finally be deleted after a while. In the latter situation any rep gained/lost by any participating member will be reverted.

Comment: This is excellent knowledge.  +1 from me and others.  Could you show me the link where this is documented ?  I really searched for it, but just couldn't find it anywhere; well, not in 30 minutes.

Comment: @User.1 _"Could you show me the link where this is documented ?"_ I'm afraid there isn't one. As mentioned, my answer ('s 2n part) just relied on my personal experience. The actual algorithm qualifying a user being answer banned is secret, and getting upvotes on an answer certainly pushes against it.

Comment: One caveat, if its an *old* post, and someone else deletes it (or the question it is posted on is deleted) reputation changes stay intact. I don't know all the thresholds/rules, but it does get saved.