# Loosing two points of reputation but without a downvote?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes

Today I checked my profile and I saw that I have two points less. This is something that has happened more than three times but I don't see any downvotes in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394631/octavioccl) in SO. I started to work seriously in this site since december, so, I don't know yet what other reasons could end in loosing points. Could someone explain me what happened in this case, and where could I find all the reasons that could end in loose reputation points?

Comment: It could be possible that one of the posts that you've edited when you had less than 2K reputation has been deleted.

Comment: If you [show removed posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288286/289086) you will see rep changes from posts that have since been deleted.

Comment: @MichaelT, that is exactly what It happened, thanks for your comment