# After I downvoted an answer, the answer was deleted. However, my reputation wasn't refunded

Tags: support, bug, reputation, downvotes

As titled. If I downvote an answer and the user deletes it afterwards, then shouldn't I regain the 1 reputation?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288285/does-1-reputation-from-downvoting-disappear-if-the-answer-is-deleted/288286#288286

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to caching/scripts that are only run periodically/other mysterious workings of the Stack Exchange network, it sometimes takes a few hours for the -1 reputation from a downvote to be refunded after the answer it is cast on is deleted.  If it was recent, it's not worth worrying about: you'll get it back.

If it's been a while (at least 24 hours or so) since the answer was deleted, and you still don't have your reputation back, then there might be something else up.  You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation as described at [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43004/165261) to confirm what happened, and report it as a bug if it's still not consistent.