# Losing reputation unexpectedly without being listed within the reputation tab

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reputation

Yesterday (24th of April 2015) I had 3,889 reputation points and the ranking at Stack Exchange still says so while on Stack Overflow my reputation is listed with 3,887 points today. Though the reputation list on Stack Overflow doesn't display any change the last two days. See the following screenshots:

[image: Reputation history on Stack Overflow]
[image: Reputation on Stack Exchange ranking list]

So I am wondering how this can be. Where did those two reputation points go? Is that a bug on SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A post you had edited (and gained +2 for the suggested edit) was deleted.

#### See also: [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history)

Comment: Thank you for the info. What you missed to mention is that I have to check *show removed posts* at the reputation history to see this info.