# Why did this unupvote/upvote result in a gain of +10 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, upvotes

To my joy, I noticed that I'd gained 10 reputation points today for an answer I'd written a while ago:

[image]

This looks, to me, like a user retracted their upvote and then immediately reinstated it (the two events happened 3 seconds apart).

My confusion arises because of the fact that I didn't *lose* 10 points for the unupvote (as I thought I would), but did *gain* 10 for the re-upvote.

The FAQ pages (such as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history/269654#269654)) don't seem to explain the behaviour above, so why did this happen? Am I getting Internet points that I don't deserve?

---

*Speculation*: the [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30100725/3923281) concerned was quite popular when I posted it several months ago, causing me to hit the daily reputation cap for upvotes. It's possible that the original upvote happened after I'd hit this cap and so didn't give me any extra reputation at that time. This could mean the unupvote didn't cost me any reputation today, but the re-upvote behaved like a normal upvote and gave me +10.

Comment: Your speculation is correct.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is this the intended behaviour for re-upvoting or might it be changed in future? (I can't see how this could be exploited in any particularly dishonest way, just curious to know whether it's an intended feature of Stack Overflow's voting system.)

Comment: @ajcr: it is a consequence of how the reputation cap works, yes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Very interesting. Out of curiosity, would it have mattered which user had done the unupvote action? ie say the OP had 21 upvotes on that day; only the 21st one resulted in zero points originally. Would that specific user have had to be the one doing the unupvote/upvote today to get this effect (because his vote was the one that originally had zero score), or could it have been any of them?

Comment: @Simba: no, because the cap would be re-calculated on that day to account for the missing vote. The 'removed' vote is then still worth 0 points.

Comment: Wow 31 seconds I guess you had already prepared both the question and answer before posting.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Your speculation is entirely correct.

The post in question caused you to reach the reputation cap several times back in early May (between the 7th and 11th of May you capped every day but one because of it). The voter in question must've upvoted it then.

Then you edited the post (last time on June 18th), thereby unlocking any votes on the post, allowing any of the voters to undo theirs if they so wish.

Then today, someone who had voted during one of your cap-reaching days undid their upvote, and re-voted immediately. The old vote never gained you any points as you were already capped at the time, but since you are not capped today, the vote gives you +10 points.

This is all a consequence of how vote capping works on Stack Exchange.

Comment: If there would be a Sherlock Holmes badge you would definitely got this one for this answer: `Sherlock Holmes gold badge: ✓` *Find something which only a detective could find (This badge can be awarded multiple times.)*

Comment: @Rizier123 But he's a ninja, not a detective. By the way, Martijn Pieters, where'd you get your profile image from?

Comment: @canon I suppose so.

Comment: @Jashaszun: Someone once branded me an *invisible framework coding ninja*, a phrase I liked and have used as a tagline ever since. When I first joined Stack Overflow I just Googled for ninja images, and that one struck me as the right balance between a Ninja and being 'approachable'. That's it, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well that image is very appropriate, as you've always stood out to me as being approachable, in Meta and elsewhere. :)

Comment: I'm left wondering if it would be considered appropriate behavior to use this to ensure a user gets rep from a vote. If I discover a person has hit the cap for the day, sometimes I hold off voting because I think the answerer deserves the reputation. This could be used similarly if you upvote and then later discover they've hit cap. @Jashaszun One might argue that Batman would qualify as both. He certainly has both skill sets. So Martijn is a StackOverflow's Batman?

Comment: Martijn is the True detective.

Comment: This must be one heck of a post. Congratulations, OP, your sneaky advertising just worked on me.

Comment: @JustinMorgan: Seems like a classy way to get over the 20k to me!