# Why my profile get added 2 reputation and removed as well

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-history

I have experienced a problem This morning when I opened SO I found my reputation is added +2 to my profile this too reflected in my profile I checked the reputation tab there was no approved edit or so that let me earn the +2.

Just before some time my reputation showing -2, Please see screenshot

[image]

Again I do not know why and how. Any clue...

Comment: From the FAQ: [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history)

Comment: To summarize, since that is a long answer: Scroll to the bottom of your rep page and click the "Show removed posts" checkbox. It's likely a question you suggested an edit to was deleted.

Comment: yes, got it... thanks @Kendra