# Is there notification when you lose reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, notifications, reputation-history

Example:

Yesterday my reputation was *702*, today is *630*. I found that one of the questions I got *+40* points is closed or deleted. But, I've trouble figuring out how the rest of *32* points got revoked.

### Question:

1. Is there any notification I get, or any way I can research it on my own based on my activity or something similar.
2. Is it possible points for post editing to be revoked? (as it appears this is the only explanation in my case)

### Edit:

Just read the statistics, as I said, single subtraction of *-42* points is marked, the rest 30 points are still mystery for me.

### Question #2:

What am I not reading right (or not taking into consideration)?

### Edit #2:

After few hours of following the advice of the community and reading the relevant posts I'm still unable to figure out where these *30* points are lost. Despite that the question is answered and covered in its greatest part, I'd greatly appreciate any ideas regarding the last, less significant part.

Comment: Yes, and see: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3313438/simplicis-veritatis?tab=reputation for your reputation history

Comment: @BradleyDotNET great, thanks! Reading....

Comment: You might also need to check the "Show Removed Posts" box.  A lot of times reputation gains/losses are hidden by that.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET that "show removed posts", so small and so in the corner :)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Exactly! :)

Comment: See also [How to audit your reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history)

Comment: @ryanyuyu OK, I guess, I'm going to wait for 24 hours to complete and then, edit and renew the question. In the mean time I'll try to go through all the described possibilities again.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'm wondering what the removed post was. Could you put a link to it here?

Comment: @durron597 it says page not found :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486770/what-does-v15-v12-0-mean/32486903#32486903

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've already learned in the comments, you can view reputation changes related to removed posts by checking the "show removed posts" checkbox in the very bottom of the reputation tab; most reputation losses will be shown there. See: [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653/1768232)

---

As far as the answer itself, thanks for providing the link to the [question. (10k-link)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32486770/1768232). Note that you need 10k reputation or above to see other peoples deleted questions and answers (you cannot see an answer if you cannot see the question).

Bad questions (current score -5, closed as *unclear what you're asking*) like that one tend to be rapidly deleted by 20k+ users if they are attracting reopen votes, as that one was (it currently has three reopen votes on it). It's pretty normal for high rep users to want to delete garbage questions pretty quickly to prevent any chance of them being reopened, especially in a heavily moderated tag like [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

You can avoid working hard on an answer just to see it disappear by not answering bad or off-topic questions. See: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Try to limit your contributions to *good* questions, and this won't happen to you very often or at all.

Comment: I see, well, it makes sense.  From now I'll try to target more well defined, structured and written questions.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis It's a hard lesson, I know. It doesn't help that so many off-topic questions have managed to avoid moderation and are taken to be examples - but knowing what the standards are _meant_ to be will help you focus your time where it will do the most good for you & the community.

Comment: @durron597  lastly, what is your advice regarding the "unexplained" subtraction of  _30_ points, not displayed in the stats? (P.S. : now more than 24 hours have past)

Comment: Why is that considered a bad question? I can totally see someone being confused by a construct like that if they've never seen it before and don't yet have a good mental model of how the language works.

Comment: @MarkRansom it's a pretty trivial operator-precedence question, and those get asked a lot (and see how many rapid answers it gained). Personally, I would have tried to close as a duplicate (operator-based questions are admittedly hard to search for if you don't know the keywords). Also, if the asker doesn't understand precedence, it seems they've jumped in at the deep end trying to read disassembled code…

Comment: _tend to be rapidly deleted by 20k+ users if they are attracting reopen votes_ - there's something slightly undemocratic-sounding about that (although I'm sure this kind of thing has been thrashed to death in previous meta conversations I haven't read)

Comment: Closed as a duplicate, OK I can totally see that. But deleting is a bit harsh.

Comment: @MarkRansom: personally, I'm in favor of deleting such questions, mainly because IMHO people ought to be discouraged from spending time writing new answers to questions like that. In an ideal world, people wouldn't encourage bad questions like that by answering them, and we could just leave the question undeleted but closed as a dupe. But we don't live in an ideal world. I don't see why SO needs dozens of different answers to the same question, especially one that is so easily answered by any basic language reference.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I believe that it's a *benefit* to have duplicate questions on the site, because you never know how someone is going to search for something. One question or the other might show up at the top of Google's list while the other doesn't appear at all. And it might be opposite for the next person.

Comment: @MarkRansom why are you talking about duplicates? The question was closed as unclear.

Comment: @MarkRansom: there is benefit to a _limited_ number of duplicates. But even there, only for questions that actually add something useful to the SO repository. Basic language syntax questions are just _so_ basic that I see no reason to encourage them at all. In any case, we certainly don't need 20 or 30 different answers spread over several different questions, all explaining the _exact_ same thing. I get that people get excited when they see a question that they actually know the answer to, but really...it's not helping.