# Reputation changes without history record

Tags: support, reputation-history

I see my reputation gets higher (i see it in toolbar), later suddenly it decreases to back. Today it happened 2 times, in front of my eyes.

There is not any relevant record in reputation history (i checked `show removed posts` box).
Why its happening ?

Comment: It could be that somebody upvoted an answer or question of yours, and reverted that action within a couple of minutes (before you checked your reputation history).

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269654/4320665) has it.  It's buried, but same day reversals "collapse into each other and are not displayed in your reputation history. This was primarily done to prevent users from spamming a user's reputation history with consistent events reversing each other. "

Comment: You didn't have any upvotes today that *remained*, so all that happened was that someone upvoted a post of yours then clicked again undoing their vote.

Comment: also it's only seen in the right side (where the total score appears), but there was not any notifications (left side).