# Is there any way to check how much reputation I had on a specific date?

Tags: support

Is there any way to check the total reputation I had on a specific date in the past?

Any Stack data sql queries?

Comment: Using the reputation tab in your activity page doesn't suffice? The graph view is pretty damn good.

Comment: You could go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and make a script/program to do the calculations for you based on the data provided. Also see: [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation

Comment: @Jim: The graph shows how much you *gained/lost*, not how much you *ended up with*, so it's not useful for this purpose at all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy you learn something new every day :-)

Answer (score 8):

Your [network-wide reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/3809296/starkeen?tab=reputation) shows this information on hover. For example, you had 3790 SO reputation on August 1, 2015.

Comment: @starkeen why did you lose 1000+ reputation from May 22nd to June 1st of this year?