# Is "unaccept" of an answer logged somewhere

Tags: support, unaccepted-answer

I could've sworn I've had one of my answers accepted yesterday. Today, I see it is no longer accepted.

Is the "unaccept" action logged anywhere? I **don't** see it anywhere under "Reputation" tab on my profile nor when I check the link `stackoverflow.com/reputation`

Comment: "Unaccept" events are *supposed* to be listed in the "reputation" tab of the profile, at least according to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history). Do you remember which question/answer it was?

Comment: Hmm, then maybe I'm delusional. However it seems suspicious that the OP was completely rewritten ~3h after getting the answer...

Comment: You should be able to see accept/unaccept events on a post's timeline. Note that if reputation events that cancel each other out occur within a certain time period - they just disappear (imagine someone spamming someone's timeline by upvoting/un-upvoting/upvoting/un-upvoting etc...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35730775/timeline shows no accept (or unaccept).

Comment: @NathanTuggy sounds like it's the right post - so either the OP is imagining it, confusing it with the post they did get an accept for yesterday, or the accept/un-accept was done so quickly, it ended up getting cancelled out (ie: neither event appears anywhere)

Comment: @NathanTuggy hey that's a nice feature. But can I trust it to see the case Jon mentioned - when the answer was accepted and quickly unaccepted afterwards without any other activity in between?

Comment: @radoh: I don't know what the exact timeframe is, but I'd think it's on the order of minutes or less. So unless they were pretty quick on the draw, it should be there.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to let people get away with radically changing their question *after* you've answered it. I've rolled that edit back. If he changes it again, feel free to flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, that's why I posted a comment to that question, asking OP why he/she changed it. I see you reverted it, thanks ;)