# Find unaccepted answers losing their acceptance

Tags: discussion

We know that: if one of my formerly accepted answers loses accepted status: I get −15 points. But where can I see a list of my unaccepted answers easily? I don't find it possible from either data dump or SEDE.

There are two approaches so far I can think of:

1. I can filter my unaccepted answers by using https://stackoverflow.com/users/your-user-id/?tab=reputation
2. Using the API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history

Is there a good way to find my unaccepted answer list easily from query somewhere? Since I want to automatically find accepted answers losing their acceptance for a user. In method 1, crawling is needed; in method 2, it may also be intense (I'm not sure).

I'm wondering what is the best way to do this.

I tried both methods manually. For example, on May 16 I can find an unaccepted tag for this user: 5050667. However, when I try with API /users/{ids}/reputation-history, it seems there are more unaccepted records.

Comment: I think a [post's timeline should record accept/unaccept events](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318069/is-unaccept-of-an-answer-logged-somewhere#comment316051_318069).  So you could maybe write a script to spin through your answers' timelines or something?

Comment: If you trust me and the [code I've written](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/se-reputation-audit?path=public/client.js:38:14) you can audit your reputation live [here](https://se-reputation-audit.glitch.me/) but you need to authenticate and allow access to the private_info. Otherwise you can remix that project and/or copy the code to host it your self. I've just added an extra block that lists the post_ids that were unaccepted.

Comment: @ryanyuyu you think so? have you tested it? I tested their method and it is not working. In timeline it doesn't show such history.

Comment: @pnuts its just an example, you get the idea, I want to know how

Comment: @pnuts I know how to do that :) see my question method 1. I want to know how to do it automatically?

Comment: @rene I want to know how to do it for not only me. So you basically implemented method 2 in my question, right? Can it be done without typing users info? I'd like to know if method 1 (crawling all reputation pages) is the only way to do it if I want to get the list not only for myself.

Comment: SEDE certainly hasn't that data so the Stack API is your only viable option. And yes, method 2 is the way to go and it turns out you don't need to be authenticated to find the reputation events you're after. That you find multiple unaccept events for that example user is because they have a similar amount of accept votes for that same post, so there is no surprise there.

Comment: @rene Thank you! It is very helpful! I tried method 2. Does it still have a daily cap of 10000 fetch, or I can fetch without any worry. I'm not sure if I need to set the fetch to be 1 second per fetch or anything else to avoid overload some cap requirement. I don't understand your explanation about that user having similar amount of accept votes. My point was, I think the API has more unaccepted reputation event than his reputation page. Maybe that is because the API has the complete records, but the reputation page removes frequent events?

Comment: yep, 10000 per day is the max for calls with a key, see [throttle](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle). And you're still subject to IP throttling as well. I've written answers about that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243798) and [here](https://stackapps.com/a/7692)

Comment: @rene very helpful! "accepted" comment : )

Comment: So... the placeholder text on the comment field includes "Avoid answering questions in comments." ... Since you guys have figured out what the answer is, could you perhaps post it as an answer?