# What happens to reputation gain?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, upvotes

I have a small question about reputation gain.

Consider a user has 15 reputation points in an account, then he votes up some answer.
After some point in time his/her reputation goes below 15. Then what would happen to the upvoted answer?

**Is that upvote reversed or not?**

Comment: The upvoted/accepted  answer isn't affected.

Comment: It will be affected if the whole question is deleted though.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653/1079354

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upvotes stay as they were. Only if an account is deleted, the votes could get invalidated. Also if a post is a deleted the reputation gain is reversed, as it never happened.