# Finding what a user's reputation was awarded for

Tags: support, reputation

How can I find what users were awarded their scores for? Looking through the profile Activity tab and various sub-tabs, I can't find any stats that show what their reputation was awarded for, for example in percentage:

- 2% - own answers upvoted or accepted
- 1% - asking questions
- 60% - own question upvoted
- 20% - bounties

Is this info available at all on SE, and for what user privilege categories?

Comment: The information is available on a per action basis and in graph plotted by day, but there are no percentages available that I know of that show what percent of the overall rep came from what actions. but it's probably a good bet that the majority gained most of their rep through receiving answer upvotes and checkmarks.

Comment: @Kevin B In a daily graph, what does 15/25 score or answers mean?

Comment: 15 would mean they received the checkmark, and +25 would mean they received the checkmark and an upvote (15 + 10 = 25)

Comment: Thanks. What user privilege categories can see, whom a user received the checkmark or upvote from? Does the system monitor possible abuse in upvoting & accepting answers, and what are the penalties?

Comment: you can't see who upvoted or downvoted a post, but the checkmark always comes from the user who created the post. Yes, there's a good bit of fraud prevention in place.

Comment: @yellowantphil That query says "Enter your UserID". Does it mean one can check only his own rep by running this query, but not a different user's? When I tried to check a certain user, it gives "Invalid column name 'username'. Did you try running it lately? May be it needs some updates?

Comment: @Kevin B I assume by checkmark you mean an accepted answer? There's also a star "Favorite question", but it doesn't seem to affect the score?

Comment: "favorite" does nothing for score. it's no different than bookmarking the question in your browser, only it's not as easy to use.

Comment: Thank you both of you for providing clear direct answers in comments so fast. :)

Comment: So, running the query for a certain example user number, I found (s)he got 80% of the rep for the last years explicitly for upvoting others answers, while other rep increase categories added almost no scores for that user. In this case, would the system cross check a group of user IDs and IPs for possible rep abuse? Are there any penalties for doing that? Since upvoting an answer doesn't require showing competence in that tag subject by having own questions and answers under the same tag category, this activity seems to be an easy subject to abuse to gain scores fast?

Comment: Is there a daily limit for upvoting others answers?

Comment: You don't get rep for upvoting others' answers. The "Upvote Answers" column in that query should probably be "Upvoted Answers", since I believe it refers to upvotes on the user's answers.

Comment: OK, found daily [limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes). Apparently, by fully using these limits, a not so scrupulous user can gain a few thousand reps per week without asking or answering any questions whatsoever, i.e. without any meaningful contribution to this site. Not surprising, earned such easy way privileges in turn can easily be abused, since the user would loose practically nothing in case of penalty (ever?), since no real reputation was hard earned anyway.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan Now I'm at loss. I wanted to research a user with 50K+ rep. By running the query I found vast majority of his rep is earned by upvoting answers. I looked at his answers, and almost none get more than 2-3 upvotes, and total is well below 100 answers. In this case, how did this user get his 50K+ rep, if he is engaged in no other meaningful activity reflected by that report? Is that a fake rep altogether?

Comment: Now I'm looking at reputation award [rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Would someone explain or give a link clarifying what "_example you contributed to is voted up: +10_" really means? Can such examples come in a form of Comments in others posts that get upvoted? What does it mean "contributed to" - at what length? How many users totally can be awarded rep from one such "example"? Are such rep awards added by the system or mod?

Comment: Please ask questions as questions, not comments. The "example contributed to" stuff is for the Documentation Beta.

Comment: Thanks Mike, its all within my attempt to research what a user rep was awarded for. Keeping up with my research, the example user earned 15K based on the above report for his answers being accepted by other users. But... each accepted answer gives 15 scores. For about 50 answers, even if all were accepted that user would max receive 750 total. Where 15K came from? Can rep be awarded for accepting answers to questions asked by others?

Comment: Here is the report graph for the example [user] (https://s32.postimg.org/xg0o41bvp/jonrsharpe.jpg). It shows that 75% of total rep 50K was earned by upvoting his answers, and 15% by accepting his answers. But when I looked at his 50 answers, only a small portion of those were notably upvoted, others receive small number or no upvotes. Only about half of his answers were accepted at the time I did a screenshot of his answers list. This results in about several folds total rep mismatch in my calculation, where his rep numbers are greatly inflated compare to actual rep earned. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Besides, vast majority of questions and answers of the example user were generic in nature, and didn't seem to require any specific qualifications in any particular field, or any specialized education and experience, which is quite strange for a site like SO targeting pros. Now, looking at this reputation example, would such example user be considered a reputable authority with demonstrated competence in a variety of fields were (s)he is allowed to cast votes due to posted privilege level?

Comment: Hi  yellowantphil . Thanks for your feedback. I made screenshots yesterday, and that example user had [52 answers] (https://s32.postimg.org/hsdmarcxx/jonrsharpe2.jpg) and 4 questions. After reading this thread he might have requested to merge his acc with another user acc, probably also run by him, or possibly abandoned. Strange thing is, the rep stays the same, while number of answers shown today sharply increased. It may indicate unauthorized or privileged access to SO server. This causes the questionhow to check history of acc merges for a SE user?

Comment: Also, for the same user, votes cast yesterday: 1674. Today: 28,579 votes cast. Its a huge difference. Does it mean hacking SE server, or there can be another explanation for that? Similar sharp difference with Posts edited and Helpful flags between yesterday and today. I checked his profile several times before yesterday, it stayed at 52 answers for several days when I was checking.

Comment: The reason I looked at this particular example user is quite simple. He suggested me quite persistently to do more research on SE stats, rules and other, so I complied, and starting from his acc rep sound logical, since he ignored my questions similar to posted above yesterday.

Comment: So I run "Old User Names" tool for the example user, and it gave me more [info] (https://s32.postimg.org/4lyz4lvdh/jonrsharpe3.jpg) for my research to work on, in terms of which of these user names are no longer accessible on SO, meaning they likely were merged with a different acc, thus merging reps as well. But again, if rep display complies with SE published practices for all users, it can't possibly stay exactly the same after accs merge, if both had reps before, especially quite notable ones? Am I right?

Comment: Can such discrepancy also result from showing different questions list for a given user on each SE site, while at the same time showing the same rep score for each site? That might have caused the mix up in stats calcs?

Comment: @ yellowantphil  Thanks for the explanation. I was trying to figure this out as well. Good learning experience. :)

Comment: @yellowantphil If that's the case, do you know of a similar AccMergeHistory tool for the site?

Comment: @yellowantphil At least it sounds like a way to differentiate btw "Change name" and "Merge profile" events on SO. Will see if it works.

Comment: Is this a [FAQ proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed)?

Comment: I added the corresponding tag to the question allowing to view below Community answer as FAQ proposal. Not sure though, if that's enough, or there are other requirements? As well, not sure if all high rep users are interested to inform the community how their rep scores were earned. This means, a flow of downvotes may be expected attempting to close or even delete the question... and answer. :)

Comment: @Makoto I added the tag "FAQ-Proposal" in response to someone's suggestion. You deleted that tag. Would you care to explain why? Does it mean it no longer can be considered a FAQ Proposal, and that was the primary purpose to delete the tag? Generally, what would it take to add the below answer to FAQ?

Comment: For context, [what the tag is meant for is available here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/faq-proposed/info).  I removed the tag since it doesn't seem like an FAQ topic.  You're asking for general information at best, or for a feature request otherwise.  I don't see it as something that would merit the faq-proposed tag.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for the link. So, who would decide eventually, whether this question should be added to FAQ or not? Also, if another user will edit the question and add FAQ-Proposal tag to it, would you continue to edit it indefinitely to remove that tag? In other words, are there any Edit privilege limits per question? :)

Comment: I'd probably only do it once more then flag a moderator for intervention, since I genuinely don't see it as an FAQ entry.  You're not asking something that occurs frequently; you're curious about this and thus far, I've only seen yourself interested in it.  FAQ entries are really meant for questions that are frequently asked.  I would not encourage you to add the tag again, but rather encourage you to peruse questions in the tag to see what kinds of questions are written that are in there.

Comment: Rest assured, I don't have a habit to override other users. The main reason is, I believe in fundamental democratic values such as the right of every individual to freely express their views even if they are opposite to mine. In context of this forum, it means I never edit other folks edits, unless they are malicious in nature, or a different part of the question may benefit from edit. :)

Comment: As to me being curious about it, your assumption is wrong. You can look through my questions put on hold to find more. I faced what I see as certain privilege abuse on this site that is apparently quite frequent based on what I managed to read so far. That prompted me to do some research to find out, whether privilege abuse can be linked to such privileges earned in illegal way, and as such not so valuable for an abuser.

Comment: Be that as it may...this isn't an FAQ request . I don't see any reason why it should be tagged as such.  That's about all I've got on the matter.

Comment: Now, whether this belongs to FAQ, I didn't initially think about it, later prompted by a user. Now I think it may, since concept of "reputation" is central to this site. As such, it would only be natural to explain users how to find out what a user's reputation was awarded for. I see similar "rep audit" Qs asked before. In a good way, it would be useful to see such data for some users you truly respect and want to learn more about. However, I'm not sure how frequent such Qs are. :)

Comment: Please note that targeting specific users (hi!) is strongly discouraged. I didn't ignore your comments, I don't see them if you **spell my name wrong** (which, given that you get an autocomplete for it, seems a bit daft). Given your repeated misunderstandings of how, when and where users earn rep (which is, as usual, in the Help Center) and inability to distinguish between Meta (inevitably generic) and Main contributions, I can only suggest again that you try to learn about this site before dumping endless complaints into Meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get an idea of where a user's reputation came from is to look at their profile. Note that Meta sites share their reputation with main sites (activity on Meta appears in the Meta profile, but doesn't have any impact on reputation) so you need to make sure you're on their main site profile, e.g. : `http://stackoverflow.com/users/<User ID number>?tab=profile`.

Firstly, you can look at their **top badges** and **top posts**, which give you a high-level idea of what they spend their time on and what their highest-rated posts are. For more detail, you can switch to the reputation tab on the activity part of their profile (`http://stackoverflow.com/users/<User ID number>?tab=reputation`), where you can see post by post where their reputation came from.

---

If you want a summary of some of the sources of rep, you can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, which offers [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220825/my-reputation-graph#graph). Enter the user ID number to get a plot for all major activities resulting in rep awards, as follows:

- *Upvote question*: rep gained from upvotes on questions the user has asked (+5 per vote)
- *Upvote answer*: rep gained from upvotes on answers the user has provided (+10 per vote)
- *Downvotes own Q and A*: rep lost from downvotes on the user's posts (-2 per vote)
- *Accepted Answers*: rep gained from the user's answer being accepted by the OP (+15 per answer)
- *Suggested Edits*: rep gained from suggesting edits that were subsequently accepted (+2 per accepted edit; note that there is an all-time cap of 2,000 on this, and users with more than 3,000 rep can no longer earn rep from edits)
- *Bounties Started*: rep lost from placing bounties on questions (varies)
- *Bounties Received*: rep gained from writing answers that were awarded a bounty (varies)

Note that this does not appear to include all possible sources of reputation, see e.g. [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653/3001761) for more details.

Comment: @yellowantphil Keeping up with my generic research, are there any known user accessible tools allowing to do a cross-check of votes cast on SE sites? For example, such tool would be expected to check what members serially upvoted a certain user answers, and in turn whether that user serially upvoted their answers. Its known, multiple user names aren't encouraged, but not prohibited or programmatically prevented by the SE site. Such tool would allow to reveal, if unfair rep is grossly gained fast by registering multiple accs or conspiring a few users to serially upvote each others answers.

Comment: Such a tool doesn't exist publicly, nor could it; votes are anonymous.

Comment: It looks like a useful edit, though I'm not sure why did you remove OldUserName tool from it? Even if it lists several existing accs, are these accs belong to the same user, and how you can verify that in practice? They can in fact belong to the same user, and logged in from the same IP or via different proxies. Keep in mind, purpose of this thread is auditory in nature, not user curiosity, as I explained earlier, so using tools is required, Help info is not sufficient.

Comment: *"why did you remove OldUserName tool from it?"* - because it clearly doesn't work, the results you posted were obvious nonsense, and encouraging some sort of vigilante behaviour is misguided at best. *"how you can verify that in practice?"* - you and I can't, really. Only the moderators have the appropriate tools to investigate this, so if you see suspicious behaviour flag it for them to deal with. *"purpose of this thread is auditory in nature"* - related to listening? If you mean it's to do with auditing, leave that to mods and SE employees, who actually have the access to do it properly.

Comment: As to lets call it "CrossVoteCheck" tool I mentioned, it might have been developed by a 3rd party, since voter anonymity can theoretically be exploited by certain users to circumvent fair collection of rep scores, as in the example given above. Its nice if a similar tool is regularly run by SE server to keep the system in sane state, but I don't know its the case, and independent user audits can be run in suspicious cases. :) One typical case is serial privilege abuse, which hints the audit is due as the user doesn't value their reps much (assuming effective abuse punishment is in place).

Comment: Your thoughts about mod and staff investigations make sense. The problem I see is to what degree mods who are community members are willing to block inappropriate or abusive & oppressive conduct if it becomes part of the site culture and exhibited by more than one member at a time, but several at once. I noticed that in some cases mods don't want to interfere with "the crowd" given their flag comments despite proper assessment. That's why independent user audits IMO are required components to keep the site in sanity state and friendly for all user categories.

Comment: Let's not get carried away here; what you describe as *"serial privilege abuse"* is me pointing out that you keep being wrong, and *"independent user audits"* is obsessive people pursuing personal vendettas over misperceived wrongdoing by wasting their free time on paranoia. Again, if you see **actual suspicious voting behaviour** then flag it for mods, but this isn't it.

Comment: That's why I suggested certain barriers in other threads, like demonstrated competence, anonymous mandatory comments, edits quality thresholds, etc. They are aimed to balance certain negative trends in the existing on Meta culture, criticized in many independent sources by SO high rep members themselves. User run member rep audits is just another component in the chain ensuring the site sanity and friendliness for all user categories. However, you understand, these are just proposals, and users have no control to have them implemented.

Comment: Hence, the trend to suppress these proposals at the start and hide them from other users is overprotective of the existing privilege system, and IMO highly negative, since it doesn't allow user majority to express themselves on Meta, suppressed by small minority. This means, the site looses plenty of useful feedback, and it negatively affects its development. We do realize, the site is someone's business, not ours, so why care? Because let's face it, its quite useful for large number of people, and many folks want it to develop and improve to feel its their own "home", not someone else's.

Comment: And, lets not forget the main thing, there're only a handful of folks in every tag category, who are willing and able to answer a question of any reasonable complexity. So some users become fans of these experts, they are grateful and want to learn more about these folks, and how they archive high scores. In that case audit tools can help as well. :) Another reason to have such tools in place is natural desire of many members to learn accelerated rep techniques, and the best way to learn them is study methods used by high rep members, just as these members did when they started here.

Comment: Returning to a user rep audit and relevant to the subject possible voting fraud, I was advised of a useful for members FAQ [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). Apparently, a script is run nightly to check this, but its not exhaustive based on my experience. :) I will suggest to add _"Low quality edit supplemented by downvote_" to its criteria set. I hope my series of proposals stated in the shortly closed by high rep users threads may be interesting to the portal decision makers.