# How do I earn more reputation points on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, new-users, privileges

I have gone through the documentation which is not quite clear on this. Can someone explain it better?

The lack of reputation points is preventing me from up/down voting answers which I believe would be very useful for the community in general!

Now, I've tried earning badges, which doesn't help bump up my reputation points. At least, Stack Overflow should enable this!
I know this question might be a possible duplicate, but I'm a bit frustrated by all these new user restrictions! (I mean, what does a guy have to do to be able to just upvote answers?! Jeez!)

Comment: first off [don't answer a question with a question, even if it's your own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40565963/1028804). a backdoor is to get rep on another SE Site and use the [association bonus](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/)

Comment: This question may already have an answer on [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com/tour): [Six simple tips to get reputation fast on any Stack Exchange site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site)

Comment: At the very least reading the introductory [tour] would be an *excellent* start.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have gone through the documentation, you might have seen this:

> Your reputation score goes up when others vote up your **questions**,
>   **answers** and **edits**.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Basically you need to be able to contribute quality posts/content. If you do not have any questions or are not able to answer questions, perhaps you could start by [improving existing questions which will net you 2 points per accepted edit, up to your first 1000 rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334014/584192).

The fastest way you can earn reputation, is by providing the best answer to a [question with an active bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size).

For a full list of ways you can earn/lose reputation points, see this FAQ topic
[Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history/269654#269654),
as well as the official help documentation
https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: (small) nitpick. Edits don't get upvoted, only accepted. And that only works below 2000 reputation. Maybe the tour could be clearer than that.

Comment: @Magisch That was quoted verbatim from the tour page. I clarified it in the paragraph below.

Comment: Like I said, maybe the tour should be clearer on that.

Comment: I created a [feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337819/correct-imprecise-wording-about-gaining-reputation-on-the-tour-page) to that effect.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs!