# Correct imprecise wording about gaining reputation on the tour page

Tags: feature-request, new-users, tour-page

Currently, our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page on the topic of reputation reads:

> Your reputation score goes up when others **vote up** your questions,
>   answers and edits.

This wording is very imprecise. Edits can not get upvoted, only approved, and neither do they give reputation beyond 2000 (or 1000 max).

I would suggest changing the wording to something that acknowledges that better, like:

> Your reputation score goes up when others **vote up** your questions or
>   answers, or when your suggested edits get approved.

This makes it clear that:

- Only *suggested edits* count to get you reputation
- That they don't get voted up, only approved.

Optionally, a small explaination about the 1000 reputation cap on suggested edits could be added, but I don't think thats quite necessary in the tour, as most people never hit that cap.

Comment: _non-community wiki_ posts are up-voted

Comment: *and neither do they give reputation beyond 2000 (or 1000 max).* actually you can still gain suggested edit rep after you hit 2K rep.  All tag wiki edits are suggestions until you hit 20K.  At that point you can no longer suggest an edit.

Comment: Hmm, that wasn't written by a programmer.  Sometimes that is a good thing, we do tend to get a bit long-winded.