# Reputation lost and there's no explanation

Tags: support, documentation, reputation, reputation-history

This is very annoying and frustrating. Yesterday I had close to 2K reputation and today I have 1.6K. Almost 400 points vanished. No warning, no comments, no downvotes. Nothing apparently changed.

I searched everywhere and all my answers are there, nothing got deleted. It's very sad that I can't find what happened more easily. I should be able to see the points I had yesterday and a BIG minus today with the points lost for a certain reason. I don't care, I just want to know. But that is not what happens. From my history now, it's like those points were never there!

Do we have any alternative where I can check chronologically all the additions and subtractions my profile had for ANY reason?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history

Comment: Some things however may not appear there, such as a loss due to an adjustment in SO Docs reputation rules, or some other kind of correction that got caught by the rep recalc.

Comment: I saw this one. It does not answer my question. Even on http://stackoverflow.com/reputation the history is vanished. There is no trace of the reputation I used to have until yesterday.

Comment: Huh. You lost 305 reputation due to a global recalc that went out today. I'd guess it was something Docs related, but there's no way of knowing why your reputation changed. It could even be a bug in the way reputation gets recalculated. We'll have to see if a dev knows anything about recent changes.

Comment: What changed? Where can I find more about the recalculation?

Comment: BTW, how do you know it was 305 points? @animuson

Comment: @VictorSchröder That's recorded. We know your reputation before the recalc was 1914, and 1609 after.

Comment: This is burried a bit in the post i linked to, but this is the page i was thinking of: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation however that won't be of much help either if you don't have the same from before the rep was lost to compare against

Comment: Was this closed as off-topic? Really? If I can't ask about lost-without-reason reputation in meta, so what is actually the "topic". BTW, 47 up-voters totally disagree and 53 up-voters of the answer as well. This question is totally, totally the point of this website and is likely to happen again, as it's related to changes in the way the reputation is calculated. Of course it can't be reproduced, it is an event initiated from stackoverflow!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

animuson is correct - we did a rep recalc for all users who have contributed to Documentation earlier today. The reason was two bug fixes that went out - one was to address an issue with daily reputation caps, and the other was to fix how we tracked links from answers to Documentation. The latter can award reputation as well through votes on the example, so we figured it best to recals. My expectation was that for most people the rep should either stay the same or increase.

However, while most of reputation changes are calculated in near-real time, it's possible for things to go out of sync. Today's recalc was triggered manually, but it could've also been triggered by things like one of your posts getting deleted.

Unfortunately, as you noticed, recalcs are very destructive; they literally rewrite your rep history, which makes investigating drops tricky. The best I can tell you at the moment is "I'm sorry" and "this is possibly a loss due to *something* Documentation-related". I'm going to see if we can beef up our logging for recalcs (or if we have a stash of this information that I'm not aware of), as well as audit what actions in Docs trigger recalcs and whether any are missing from that list so we minimize the potential for large changes.

Comment: Would a feature-request asking for notifications or a trace of these changes in the private rep log in case of these recalcs make sense?

Comment: If only there were a site with a bunch of programmers somewhere where you could ask a question like "We're doing a completely destructive recalculation of a critical value on our users' accounts.  Sometimes things go wrong and we have no idea why because we destroyed all the data when we recalculated.  What sorts of design patterns might we use to avoid this problem?"  Someone should start a site like that, maybe with like karma points or something for good answers.

Comment: This answer (and also the question) is 2 days old, yet I lost 200+ reps today. Any update?

Comment: This update was deployed Friday... a perfect day to deploy changes :D

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ, Your reputation loss was a result of the [contributor list for Getting started with Java Language - Creating your first Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/378) becoming corrupted. I have [posted a question/filed a bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343581/3773011) regarding this issue.

Comment: @Makyen *contributor list for ... becoming corrupted* - it is too hard to understand. Can you explain it? I mean is it a bug (which definitely will get fixed)? Is there any chance of getting back lost reps? I am not just asking for me alone, I think it works for everyone who lost reps ;-)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ I'm on my phone at the moment.moment, so brief: Yes it is a bug. The list of contributors is corrupted. The edit data from which the table is generated looks like it still exists, so the table should be able to be regenerated. In other words, when this is resolved you should have your reputation back. However, I am only am a user, not a SE developer, so that is just my best estimate of what is going on.

Comment: However, the bug discussed in my question linked above is not the cause of the issue in this question and answer. The issues discussed here are separate.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks a bunch. I think SE developers (or Mods in the least) can see this discussion I guess, and hence I think I can wait for their *beefed up* reply.