# My Documentation reputation points have been lost and have still not reverted back

Tags: discussion

Five days ago, my Documentation reputation points was lost and there was no notification in my account about where they had gone. Some peoples' reputation points reverted back, but not mine. What is the case?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343442/reputation-lost-and-theres-no-explanation/

Comment: ok i will delete it first you have to delete your comment