# I've just lost 1760 reputation points without explanation

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, reputation

That's 22% of my reputation on SO.

Now you see them.

[image]

... and now you don't

[image]

If this is some "recalculation", then these one-sided updates without warning or explanation aren't the way to go about it.

Comment: In your case, it looks like there was a reputation recalculation, but there's no corresponding 'user was removed' or 'Voting corrected' entry that I'd expect to see *yet*. Sometimes it takes a little while for the reputation log to update.

Comment: I've asked a CM to take a peek; there isn't anything immediately obvious.

Comment: last time something like this was reported here it turned out [docs recalc](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343443/839601) @MartijnPieters

Comment: rep recalcs have some history: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010

Comment: @gnat: ah, I missed that post. I assumed that the docs reputation reshuffle had completed already. That looks like a very likely candidate now; the OP has got [enough Documentation contributions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3199595/malt?tab=documentation&sort=all) after all.

Comment: Didn't SE rewrite every single user's reputation history under the name "Documentation-induced rep recalc" long ago?

Comment: Your reputation loss was caused by the [contributor list for Creating and Initializing Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/404) being corrupted.  I have posted another [question specifically reporting this bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343581/3773011). Based on [your edit to that example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/59738?filter-tags=java) and that [Arrays is listed, but not the specific example](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3199595/malt?tab=documentation&sort=contributions), this is certainly what caused your reputation loss.

Comment: @Makyen nice catch.

Comment: I'm reopening since this drop is not the result of the manual recalc we did on Friday. I have no idea off-hand what the actual cause is, unfortunately. @Makyen's post sounds plausible. I'll investigate further when I'm back at the office tomorrow.

Comment: @AdamLear May this have to do with the documentation bug where contributor lists get corrupted?

Comment: @Magisch: that's what Adam is referring to; that's Makyen's post.

Comment: One does not simply lose 22% of imaginary internet points without telling everybody...

Comment: Do you screenshot your SO bar every day?

Comment: 1760 rep off just one documentation edit? How broke is that thing!!?!

Comment: @Lankymart: Very.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I two tabs open while the change took place.

Comment: @Malt: Fortunate :)

Comment: @Lankymart First, I'm not sure that it's all from that one edit, although it might be. Second, the **entire reputation system is broken**; this has nothing to do with documentation specifically. The reputation system always favored popularity over quality or effort. Take a look at the list of [most up-voted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36656/most-upvoted-answers) on stack overflow. Most of them are simple answers to simple, but popular, questions.

Comment: @Malt that the reputation system disproportionately rewards answers to popular questions doesn't make it "broken" - on the contrary, it's a sensible incentive system that rewards answers that benefit many people over answers that benefit few people. It doesn't make it a better measure of how good a programmer or how worthy a human being you are, but *does* make it a better measure of how much good your answers have done in the world. Now, rep for Documentation contributions (which don't really appear on Google, are only voted on by other rep-chasers, and have probably never helped *anyone*)...

Comment: @Makyen [that page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/404) is a nightmare...

Comment: @MarkAmery: "*a better measure of how much good your answers have done in the world*" -- Not if you mean the marginal good compared to doing nothing. Because when you don't post a trivial answer to a popular question, someone else will do it, and the world will be just as well off. But giving a thorough answer to a difficult but low-visibility question, makes a read difference for at least one person (the one who asked it).

Comment: @MarkAmery I have about 2k rep from Docs. I didn't do much for it, i was just *fast*. hrm. I'll take it anyways ;)

Comment: @smls I'd think bounties solve that problem

Comment: @Makyen Data corruption of something as basic as a changelog/revision history in a production system is a _very serious problem_.  I hope there's at least one developer looking at this and working to ensure it can never happen again whilst everyone else debates whether or not the reputation system is properly balanced.

Comment: It's good that such a point is raised by @Malt.
Before deducting or changing anything with reputation points they (Stack overflow Team) should inform us.

Comment: @Ashraf.Shk786 In this case, it's a bug. It wasn't intentional.

Comment: What if someone have edited the values with Chrome > Right Click on page > Inspect Element ? I mean who knows that its 100% reliable snaps?

Comment: We're still working on this issue - it's more complicated than we first realized.  Should have an answer in the next few days.

Comment: I want to see a meta question when a person gains 1760 reputation without any explanation. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Details on the bug are in [my answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343581/documentation-example-contributor-corruption-results-in-reputation-drop/345211#345211).