# How much rep do I actually have?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, reputation

This morning, when I logged in, it appears that I have had a 926 point increase overnight... I know this, because I slept my computer overnight and was still logged into Stack Overflow, and so could get the following two screenshots...

```
   Yesterday                 Today
```

[image] [image]

Here is my rep gain recently...
[image]

So is my rep actually 2800 - or is something just bugging out?

The reason I am asking this is because we have a competition at work every month revolving around your relative point increase - Could be in for a win if it is actually 2800!

Comment: You can see the full audit of your own reputation by going to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: Wow, you lucky guy

Comment: I notice that you've contributed to Documentation, it may have something to do with the weirdness around Docs rep right now.

Comment: @TinyGiant I do have many points invested in SO Docs. And got hit pretty hard when they changed the point system around that previously. Do you think that this is just a temporary error in regards to this?

Comment: Confirming that this is to do with documentation reputation. One of the documentation devs will be looking at this.

Comment: @gunr2171 I checked that link and it says 2800.

Comment: @Oded So I should not be getting excited about potentially winning the work competition ? :(

Comment: I can see a -885 a few days ago, then a +920 today. I don't know what's correct, but I assume the +920 is a correction. But - someone more familiar with documentation rep will look at things.

Comment: @Oded Ok - thanks for that! I can't see that rep fluctuation on my rep tab or on stackoverflow.com/reputation - I am assuming that's only something a mod can see..

Comment: A developer, actually - moderators don't have access to this information.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. It is a valid on-topic question that is not a duplicate, nor shows a lack of research.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think they got confused by a complaint about too much rep...

Comment: Adding this to the list of documentation rep issues I'm looking at.

Comment: The -885 is 177 Documentation votes for a major contributor, where the +920 is 184 votes. The loss and gain are consistent with what would have happened if a contribution of yours was affected by [Documentation example contributor corruption results in reputation drop](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343581). Based on [your contributions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3509591/zze?tab=documentation&sort=contributions), the only fit is if the [Using console.log()](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) example was affected.

Comment: @Makyen Interesting post. I can confirm that I also had a large reputation loss very early on after contributing to documentation - at the time I just assumed that this was a retrospective tweak to the amount of points gained for documentation 'things'. So in your opinion my new >2800 is correct?

Comment: @Zze, Your reputation loss "very early on" was probably the change that was made to how reputation was awarded (changes to the definitions of major/minor contributor and that minor contributors rep gain was 1 point/vote). That change was months ago (I'd have to search to find exactly when), and is nearly certain not to be the cause of your issue. The most recent intended changes I know about are two bug fixes [mentioned in an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343443/3773011). I have not looked at your case in detail, but those bugs probably didn't significantly affect you.

Comment: @Zze, I don't believe its possible for a non-dev to now determine specifically If the issue in the question I linked affected (i.e. after it has been corrected). I consider it likely your current rep is correct, but the only way to be sure is to go through all of your reputation changes and confirm each was correct. That's work you can do, if you want.

Comment: @Makyen Yeah I remember seeing that documentation rep change. Ok interesting, thanks.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Have you any revelations to this as of yet? End of month is tomorrow :S. (All good if not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details on the bug are in [my answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343581/documentation-example-contributor-corruption-results-in-reputation-drop/345211#345211).