# Reputation lost

Tags: support, feature-request, reputation

I lost about 500 reputation in the last 3 days. I am not sure why, I got no downvotes and none of my posts were deleted. Also my reputation log does not show any removed posts. I would guess that there was again a documentation reputation recalculation. Could someone check what is going on?

**Feature request:**
If this is really a result of a documentation based reputation recalculation I would like to have in my profile at least a hint that a reputation recalculation has happend. In best case also the actual change.

Comment: Hrm, indeed, your log shows *Scheduled: old rep = 32089, new rep = 31554* without further detail as to what the lost reputation was originally earned for.

Comment: Smells like documentation - the last staff response to this (that I'm aware of) was [Adam's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343443/).

Comment: SE is now balancing the overall reputation between its members. Thank you for supporting the poor with your rep...

Comment: @rene what you mean by this, can you explain more ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: rene is joking. He's implying the lost reputation was redistributed to those with less rep, Robin Hood style.

Comment: oh @MartijnPieters silly me.. i missed the humor in his post :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was more thinking Karl Marx style but in hindsight your suggestion might give me the popularity vote. I'll take that, thanks.

Comment: It's a conspiracy cover-up.  @rene has stolen your rep and will not be giving it away to low-rep users :)

Comment: You told you lost 500 reps in the last 3 days. So each day you were losing any particular amount of reps?

Comment: @vivz I cannot say exactly when it happened however Martijn could confirm this

Comment: It was *one* recalculation event, timestamped 2017-07-21 03:48; I posted the log entry in my first comment.