# Is the reputation widget broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, achievements-dialog

Earlier now there was a notification of reputation change. It was showing +6:

[image: +6]

But when I opened it and saw it, it was +10 because of an upvote on one of my answers:

[image: +10]

Is this a bug or did I missing something?

My reputation column in my profile:

[image]

Comment: It's probably from answers you downvoted that were deleted. You can see the +1 in the reputation tab on your profile, but not in the achievements dialog.

Comment: I never downvoted an answer till now and i didn't  understand your comment. i got exactly 10 reputation from an upvote. every thing matches but the notification score that is shown is  wrong

Comment: Could it be that you've had some suggested edits removed? By that I mean the posts have now been deleted and so you've had the rep taken back off you.

Comment: my reputation was 1695 and it went to 1705 , so my reputation increase was +10 its correct. There is no -2 in my reputation tab in my profile too

Comment: @Redman: you need to enable the checkbox that allows you to see deleted posts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The change shown is relative to the last time you clicked on the icon. You gained 6 points since you last did this.

Assuming you didn't downvote any answers (which would cost you 1 point but even moderators can't see in your history), then you probably last did this before April 13th. Since then you have had the following reputation changes (in chronological order):

- -2 on 04-13, a post you suggested an edit to and which was accepted, was removed, *delta -2*
- -2 on 04-14, a post you suggested an edit to and which was accepted, was removed, *delta -4*
- -10 on 04-15, you lost an upvote because a user was removed, *delta -14*
- -2 on 04-15, a post you suggested an edit to and which was accepted, was removed, *delta -16*
- +10 on 04-16, upvote on an answer, *delta -6*
- +2  on 04-17, a suggested edit was accepted, *delta -4*
- +10 on 04-18, upvote on an answer, *delta +6*

This is a total loss of 16 points and a total gain of 22, so the delta is +6.

Note that the widget only lights up when there is a *positive result* to report; until that last +10 change for the upvote changed the delta to a net positive, the widget would not have reported any changes in the icon. Furthermore, reputation changes for deleted posts are also not shown in the achievements dialog.

For further information (including how to enable showing reputation changes attributed to deleted posts), see [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history)

Comment: i visited the site daily then why show +6 notification now. I opened So went for lunch and came back  and it showed +6 notification it should had been +10

Comment: @Redman: only when there is a *positive change* will the widget show. You were at -4 before that last vote came in.