# Why do I see wrong notification summary of reputation change

Tags: bug

Why there is difference in summary (+8) and detail (+10) of the reputation change I've achieved today?

[image]

It has often happened with me in the past also but for the first time I was prompt to take a screengrab.

Comment: Most common scenario of reputation getting lost but not showing up is post deletion.  You may have had a post that you edited back before you had 2K rep deleted.  When that happens you lose the 2 rep points you earned back then.  And it only shows up in your reputation history if you have "show removed posts" checked

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ohh! I see that now. I wasn't aware of this `show removed posts` checkbox. I can see a removed post in my reputation tab. But why it is not showing in the details in the top bar. In the past, I've see the loss of reputation whenever a user gets removed who had upvoted my post. Isn't it something similar which should be shown?

Comment: @RBT because the details in the dropdown show reputation changes due to voting/bounties/accepts.  When a post is deleted the system treats it as it the rep never existed, so the rep was lost way back when it was earned, not "yesterday", which is a little inconsistent with the reputation tab since that shows the "removed" rep notice on the date the post was deleted.

Comment: @psubsee2003 will it be possible for you to add an answer to my question. You can convert your comment into answer. It might be helpful for future readers.

Comment: I intentionally didn't leave an answer because I was waiting for someone who knows the system better to ensure i wasn't given an incorrect answer.

Comment: @RBT I had similar question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348056/is-the-reputation-widget-broken