# "show removed posts" checkbox on tab=reputation should be moved to just above the list

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, user-experience

Like ([it appears, many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=show+removed+posts)) I was recently confused by multiple *inexplicable* drops of 2 reputation.

I came here looking for answers, and found [this excellent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history#269654) originally by [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray), which enlightened me about the existence of the "show removed posts" (one of the possibilities I suspected) checkbox:

> all the way at the bottom

What a run around to find exactly what I needed to see!

Having checked that box, I am now fully informed about the occasional otherwise baffling decrements.

**Can the "show removed posts" checkbox please be moved from the bottom `<div class="user-tab-footer">` to be the first child of `<div class="user-tab-content">` where it would sit neatly just above the list?**

This is how it looks after simply dragging the element up the DOM in Chrome's dev tools:
[image]

No more confusion or searching for reasons and/or answers; put the controls where we can see them!

Thanks.

Comment: I recently made a push to [finally implement this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes) which would make that button obsolete, but I'd consider pushing for this change if that falls through. I'd strongly prefer the other solution because it'd clear up a bunch of other confusions in the process (explaining it over and over *and over* gets a bit tedious).

Comment: I practically quadruple-take-d at `"asked 4 years, 9 months ago ... active 2 years, 1 month ago"` <-- Seriously?! A search for the words "show removed posts" reveals an epic (rather than tedious) problem with a simple solution, requiring little more than cut/paste to fix; no maths, shoehorning, endless discussion over terminology or wizardry involved. I'm truly all in favour of throwing out the rule book and starting fresh, so your solution seems like a walk in the park to me, but history begs to disagree with us both. Ask for little and get it, rather than waiting 5 years for nothing.

Comment: By recently made a push, I mean I added this to the [internal board of stuff the community team thinks needs to be implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/what-features-did-the-community-team-discuss-have-implemented-or-have-denied-l). It's *currently* pending estimation to see if it's viable to do. But we're not going to push for a feature that changes something that would otherwise become obsolete while the jury is still out on the feature that would make it obsolete.

Comment: ahhh - that's better :-) You had me worried there.