# Where is this rep coming from and why does it not add up?

Tags: support, bug, reputation

This morning I found this in my rep navbar tab.

[image: Where is the other 2 rep]

I found this strange that it says I got 13 rep in the nav, but 15 in the dropdown. Last I saw downvotes are shown in the rep tab. My profile rep tab also shows an increase of 15. What I actually got was an increase of 13.

[image: Normal Rep Tab]

Then I viewed the question.

[Trying to get property of non-object in codeigniter class my_exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136307/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-codeigniter-class-my-exception/44136412#44136412)

[image: No up votes]

I have no upvotes or downvotes on the question. I made no edit on the question. I'm at a loss. What is happening with my rep? Is this a bug, and if not, can this behavior be explained?

**Where is this rep coming from and why does it not add up?**

Comment: The 15 points are coming from an *accept* of an answer, not a vote. There are various reasons why the topnav might show +13 instead of +15. It could be including rep from another site, you could have lost 2 points from having an answer downvoted, etc. etc. [There is a way you can find out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history).

Comment: @CodyGray is my memory going bad. I thought an answer being accepted was less than than 15. Also aren't downvotes are usually visible?

Comment: The downvote could have been on another answer. I'm not sure what you mean by "visible". No, accepts have always been +15. It's 5 points more than an upvote.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history has explained it. Thanks. Sorry if this question was a waste of time. Hopefully this behavior can be more intuitive in some way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The [Top bar can't math](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210139/reputation-items-in-the-achievements-dropdown-dont-add-up)