# set bounty on question asked by other user

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

Is it Possible to put a bounty amount to a question that is not being asked by me?
And what would be minimum reputation To set bounty?

Comment: On MSE: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)

Comment: How do we not have a canonical FAQ about bounties on Meta? Am I just unable to find it, or does it actually not exist?

Comment: @CodyGray same idea here, I'm going through 419 questions atm to find a better dupe. Maybe we should bring over the MSE post?

Comment: Yeah, probably should, @rene. We need something here, if only as a dupe-target. On the other hand, we really should be able to close as a duplicate of stuff in the Help Center...

Comment: @CodyGray It's on the SE Meta site. Since it applies to every site, it didn't get migrated. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: @CodyGray I'm done, I added 4 dupes here, I couldn't find one that simply explains the minimum rep needed. I'm all for bringing the MSE post over. You take that on?

Comment: It just bothers me to intentionally duplicate content across sites. I did it once with [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history) and still feel dirty about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set bounties if you have a reputation of 75 or more.
Here is the description: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties