# Why is the 'show removed posts' checkbox disabled by default? Why is it there?

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation, reputation-history, live-refresh

**Update** It is now more or less clear that strange behaviour is by design, so I removed `bug` label, added `discussion`, because:

> **Why is the "*show removed posts*" checkbox disabled by default?** Why is it even there? I can only imagine it to be handy for trolls giving non-answers and not wanting to be pestered with the constant deletion alerts and red **-8** texts.
>
> For any new user, not being aware of answer deletions and happily spending time cranking out helpful answers that will then become off-topic, resulting in punishment, seems madness to me.
>
> Compare to downvotes. You want to see those as well, do you?

.

**PS** In [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history) I cannot find a -8 reputation loss on deletion. And also still not happy about posts count (see below)

---

**Original question** just FYI:

Yesterday (7-9 hrs ago) I had some pending edits. Not sure when they were approved, but I now notice a very long eventual consistency in the UI.

Looking at the screenshot and notice:

- **reputation history**: 3 edits today, one yesterday (totaling 8 points)
- **reputation counter** (405): does not reflect this increase yet
- **reputation increase** (+163): not sure, but think it includes the +8 points
- **recent achievements icon**: never green-lighted to notify me

I thought this was extreme eventual consistency or an error, but @jon-clements pointed to an answer deletion: https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/8295283

Now I have a couple of questions about this:

- Why didn't I get any notification of this occurrence?
- If there is a reputation penalty, why doesn't it show in my list (couldn't find it anywhere)?
- (related to eventual consistency or error): Why is `posts edited` not incremented by 3 edits (one duplicate edit), but by 2?

Overview of perceived 'inconsistencies':
[image]

And there is no mention of the answer deletion penalty (also 1 edit +2 is missing):
[image]

And the 'posts edited' does not reflect the 3 unique approved edits, only 2:
[image]

[**Update**: This is not a duplicate of [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history) as that one describes mostly valid (non-erroneous, or eventual-consistent) behaviors. I have a `posts edited count` that is not correct, and - more importantly - no notification of deleted answer, and no indication of reputation penalty anywhere]

Comment: Not a bug. Note that the roomba ran and cleaned up a question you had a +1/-1 answer on ~5 hours ago... so you've effectively got a -8 in there as well cancelling out the 4 +2's for suggested edits... (so 405 is the correct number...)

Comment: Thx. Where can I find that? Is that this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17014750 ?

Comment: @ArnoldSchrijver you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/8295283

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out (spend a lot of time helping the guy only to get punished, but okay). Very strange that I don't receive any notification of this at all!

Comment: BTW another thing I just noticed is the edit count just went up by 2.

Comment: @Arnold where you are you seeing 33/35?

Comment: In the Impact box on the right. Don't know if you can see that. I can create a screenshot

Comment: @Arnold that's correct. It's the number of *unique* posts you have edited - not the number of suggested edits you've had approved. You suggested edits to two posts twice each - a post only counts *once* towards that number.

Comment: Thx again. Of the last 4 edits only 1 was duplicate (and looked in their history.. i've not been there before). I've also added a screenshot of reputation, doesn't show the answer deletion penalty.

Comment: As I have explained in my first update this is no duplicate, imho.

Comment: Completely rephrased to latest insights..

Comment: Is the "show deleted posts" checkbox checked?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate of [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653); the deletion cost you -8 points, and *until you gain more points*, it won't be visible in the reputation notifications.

Comment: @martijn-pieters That makes no sense. So I get +8 on edits and -8 on deleted answer. The +8 are shown in reputation audit log and the -8 is not. Imagine that happened on your bank account with a write-off..

Comment: @DonaldDuck searching in UI and help, I can't find where this checkbox is located

Comment: @ArnoldSchrijver It's on the bottom of your user page in the reputation tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHjMl.png

Comment: Thanks @DonaldDuck that solved that issue. Very inconvenient and confusing behavior. Not at all clear. Just the edit count difference remaining.

Comment: Frankly your "edit" and "original" post make this thing a giant mess, and make it hard to read as I have to jump around.  Just revert to your original post and then ask a new one with your discussion.  Or since the only answer addresses your update, just remove the "old stuff".

Comment: Thanks @psubsee2003 but I have given up. This has become a mess because I am fighting overly quick downvoters and closers. Now if it is closed, so be it. I have spent way too much time already trying to improve SO, going back to work now.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your new question:

> Why is the "show removed posts" checkbox disabled by default?

Removed posts don't have any effect *at all* on your (total) reputation<sup>[1]</sup>. Showing those removed posts by default would only lead to more entries with net zero effect, and make it harder to see the 'essential' data which contributes to a user's reputation.

<sup>[1]</sup>: reputation from posts with a score of +3 or more which are deleted 60 or more days after posting is [kept after deletion](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/).

Comment: Thanks. Well, then I am back to original question: Why didn't I get +8 for 4 unique edits that had just been approved. And why do `posts edited` only increase by 2? And why has the deleted answer a weight of -8 when displayed?

Comment: There's a lot of confusion what 'posts edited' really means, because the number is different from the number on the [revisions tab on the user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=revisions) and the [editors tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors). I can't find a canonical post about that right now, sorry.

Comment: Damn, I'm being downvoted again. I give up, but **I see errors and bad UX!!**. Thanks for help @glorfindel

Comment: Just remembered - tag only edits don't count towards edited posts - so that's why only two of.your edits count @Arnold

Comment: Cool, thx. Slowly things getting solved. I still don't get the hidden -8 score. Not sure if all those edits were tag-only, but a tag-only edit gave me +2 before, so I expected a +8 (PS, I am just trying to improve SO, its not about the darn points.. this costs me my Sunday :)

Comment: And you did get +8 for the edits - it just so happens (as explained previously on your Q twice) - the +8 you had from an answer ceased to exist because it didn't meet the criteria as Glorfindel mentions... So you didn't really get a -8 penalty - it's more you just didn't get the 8 to start with. Also - look around on meta - as to why deleted posts aren't the default in addition to this answer and the (mostly declined) related feature requests surrounding it.

Comment: You'll get +2 for an approved tag only edit but it doesn't increase your edited posts count.