# Privilege calculation to use chatroom (20 reputation)

Tags: support, chat

According to [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat), 20 reputation are required to write messages in chat room. Today, I have received the following notification;
[(Notification to Chat)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXA3e.png).

There have been ups and downs today, but I have never exceeded 20 reputation points.
[(RepOverTime)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmd17.png).

How did this message emerge?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One of your answers was upvoted then accepted (taking your reputation to 26, triggering the message about gaining the chat privilege).

However, the accept was very quickly reversed - and your reputation dipped back to 11 reputation, revoking the privilege in the process.

Comment: Acceptance was not shown in reputation changelog, even if removed posts are toggled to show. Hence the question.

Comment: Where are you seeing an acceptance event on a recent answer? I'm not seeing that at all.

Comment: Secret dev ui, @CodyGray - they were 2 seconds apart, so we probably don't propagate them to the UI.

Comment: As @animuson points out in a comment to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history/269654#269654) answer, acceptance/unacceptance to answers within a day are collapsed and therefore not shown in the history.