# If a user removed his/her question, can it affect my reputation for the answer I provided?

Tags: support, reputation

Earlier today I answered a question on Stack Overflow.

I got two upvotes for my answer and my reputation increased accordingly. I also saw this new added reputation on my profile page.

A few hours later this reputation was gone, and the relevant answer is not seen in my account "answers" list. I also can't find the relevant question on the site.

I assume the question was deleted, but is this the reason my reputation decreased?

I [saw this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history) about gaining and losing reputation, but I don't think it covers such a situation.

Comment: The question you answered got deleted by 3 20k users after it was closed as unclear - so the 20 rep you received from it was effectively cancelled out.

Comment: Note that the answer seems to contradict [What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), which says, "Deleted posts do not affect reputation, for voters, authors or anyone else involved, [in most cases](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/)." The blog post linked there then contradicts the sentence, saying that "Deletions will have a much more immediate effect on reputation". Kind of confusing...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The cause of the confusion is that also the rules and engine features regarding this are confused, and changed many times.

Comment: The user can't remove his question any more if 1) it has multiple answers 2) it has at least 1 upvote on at least 1 of its answers 3) he accepted an answer. | Of course the user can un-accept your answer and then delete the question, but only if (1) and (2) doesn't apply. Thus, the answer is mainly: no. | The collective behaviour of the SE is sometimes too disadvantageous for the answerers; questions are deleted, or closed before you could answer them; sometimes the user who voted for you, are deleted (either by themselves or by a mod). Yes, it is very annoying.