# Which tags from questions are added to profile tags points?

Tags: discussion, bug, tags, profile-page

**Case:**

The question: [Why am I getting random spaces between the image grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990956/why-am-i-getting-random-spaces-between-the-image-grid/50991590)

Among other tags, it has the [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) tag.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50991590/9232222) was accepted by the OP.

**Problem:** Among my [user profile tags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9232222/august?tab=tags&sort=votes&page=1), I don't have any points for [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3). Actually that tag is not even in the list of tags.

Comment: That is accurate, you did not get any helpful votes on that post.  Its score is still 0.

Comment: Not sure what the values from before and after the tag name means from user profile page.

Comment: For example for my css tag I get 36 score out of 53 answers, if I count the votes I have 39 votes: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a9232222%20%5bcss%5d

Comment: Votes != score. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history