# How are yearly/monthly/weekly reputation points saved and recalculated after changes?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

To determine point scores for certain intervals (yearly/monthly/weekly), they have to be saved for those intervals, to my knowledge. Pseudo example:

```
userid | month   | totalpoints
213    | 2018-05 | 352
213    | 2018-06 | 457
```

Is Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange doing it like this, storing the total scores per interval? Or *really* saving the points for each interval?

**Problem:**

If points from the past get changed, e.g. a post from 2018-05 gets deleted, then the totalpoints change and the table above would hold wrong data. A complete recalculation would be necessary.

The same goes for changes in the point system...

It would be great to get some insights into this probably more complex problem/system.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Haven't known that I can see the reputation like this. So reputation is saved on a **per day basis** and from that all other interval scores are re-calculated? And if a post from the past is removed, all interval scores get updated. (If so, please add this as an answer.)

Comment: That's my assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *understanding* is that (at the very least) each End of Day is captured and so forms a reference point for the calculation that needs to be done.

A user's reputation can be monitored at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Any deductions aren't made retrospectively so any "end of day" value is never affected, only the *current* end of day.

Thus, the calculation should be simple enough*:

```
Current Rep Value - Previous EOD value = Rep Change
```

---

<sup>*I am willing to be corrected if my assumptions are in error.*</sup>

Comment: `Any deductions aren't made retrospectively` – Would be very interesting to see how the stack-developers handle a situation when the point system gets changed, e. g. upvotes on answers are raised from +10 to +12. Furthermore, now I understand from your answer, that if posts from the past are deleted, they are not changed in the past, but instead will trigger minuspoints for the current day!

Comment: Which is, by the way, not mentioned here: [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653/1066234)

Comment: If a upvote value is changed from 10 to 12 it only applies to votes *from that day forward*. There's no sweeping recalcuation nor is there any need for one.