# Decrease in reputation without any history record

Tags: support, reputation

Today several hours after signing in I saw a -15 decrease in my reputation points, but nothing in the reputation points history. Since it is -15 I understand that it is a case of an unaccepted answer and that's ok.  Also today I did not have any of my answers accepted so there is no case of balancing.

If it was the case of a user that was deleted/removed I would see it since this has happened before. But this is a phantom case.

I know that this question could be considered as duplicate because I found many questions about the same or similar situations, but I did not find any solution. 
 Is there any way I can review my actual ups and downs?

**Edit**: I found the solution by checking *show removed posts* which I had never noticed. If this question is not of any help or interest to others it can be deleted.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history Of particular interest, the **My reputation went down, but I don't see anything listed!** section

Comment: and if you really want to dig around in the nitty gritty.. there's this: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @KevinB I did all that and there is no record of -15

Comment: Doesn't really change anything, rep doesn't just disappear without a trace except for the few reasons outlined in that section.

Comment: @KevinB I'd like to think that this is the case **but** today I had a -15 and all I can see is 4x10=+40. So what can I say?

Comment: you mean, you had +55 and now you have +40, right?

Comment: The most likely scenario is a question was deleted, resulting in your accepted answer being deleted. but if you followed the directions in that post you would have been able to see that... so I can only assume you've already checked that.

Comment: @KevinB the +40 is about today. I did not get any accepted answers, only 4 upvotes. This -15 must be about an older answer that was unaccepted

Comment: If it was, there would be an unaccept event.

Comment: @KevinB If the question was deleted wouldn't that show in rep history just like when a user is deleted?

Comment: @mTak Yes, if you have the checkbox checked. You do have one unaccept over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503801/element-textviewcompat-is-not-allowed-here/51503883#51503883 but that was more than a week ago.

Comment: @KevinB This was unaccepted 2 weeks ago and I'm aware about it since then.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, the problem was that I never noticed that *show removed posts* check at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51739996/19679) was deleted when the question it was on was removed as part of a user deletion. This removed the 15 points from the accept vote you received there.

I believe you can see this in your history if you choose to show recently delete posts.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot and one favor maybe it is in front of me and can't see it, where can I see deleted posts?

Comment: Ok I found it, thanks again