# What happens to my reputation if an answer is un-deleted which I downvoted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, deleted-answers

Scenario:

1. A question receives a terrible answer
2. I downvote answer
3. I lose 1 rep
4. Answer is deleted
5. I get my rep back
6. Answer is un-deleted
7. ???

I found [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653/2191572) but it does not seem to cover this situation.

Additionally, does it matter who did the deleting/un-deleting; user vs. moderator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Undeleting an answer results in the reputation calculation acting as if it was never deleted in the first place, in just the same way that deleting a post results in the calculations being done as if it were never posted in the first place.