# Why did I get 3 reputation for an upvote?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

An hour ago, I got a +3 reputation notification, which I thought was pretty strange since I couldn't think of any action that would lead to +3. Also, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679609/how-to-make-labels-only-appear-above-certain-bars/55681575#55681575) is clearly +2/+0. Is there any explanation for this?

[image]

Commenters have mentioned the daily rep cap, which I have hit (21 upvotes). However, I didn't lose any reputation, so why did the 21st upvote give me +3?

Comment: Maximum 200 rep from vote. I guess you lost 3 reputations (perhaps by downvoting 3 answers?) after reaching the limit, thus that upvote recovered your 3 rep...

Comment: I didn't lose any rep either. That's really more the thrust of my question; if it was *just* the rep cap, where did the +3 come from?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: Given the +3 puts you above the rep cap, I'd guess there is a deletion hidden in there where you lost 3 rep points.  This is often helpful for figuring out your rep changes: [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history)

Comment: @Stijn I did. It doesn't tally with my profile (it says +245, my profile says +248)

Comment: There is a very limited group of people on SO that can actually review your exact reputation change. The general public here can't. And frankly, to be blunt, hunting down the exact cause of this +3 is not a good use of moderator time. Either some event you didn't notice happened, or there was a recalculation error of some sort. We're unlikely to ever know.

Comment: Like @StoryTeller said, except *you* are one of the people who can dig into your own reputation history to figure out what happened, if you care. Closing as a duplicate of the FAQ that explains how.

Comment: My guess is that you downvoted 3 answers today. There must be a 3 rep drop somewhere to allow the final vote of the day to recover those lost points.