# Does StackOverflow penalize you by not entering the site daily?

Tags: support, reputation

I got a problem with stackoverflow, I've noticed that if I spent more than two days without participating actively on the site (reviewing posts, voting down up, answering questions) my reputation downs by two points per inactive day, and you aren't notified.

Is this a normal function? I mean, what if take vacation for a week my reputation will be affected.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: I usually observe the opposite effect. My reputation climbs faster when i'm not actively using the site.

Comment: Your reputation history also shows no evidence of your rep going down recently due to actions that are not of your control (such as casting downvotes on answers)

Comment: Probably because all the information you need to answer the question is in your profile.

Comment: Being inactive does not change your reputation at all.

Comment: I know that Kevin B, but it's strange that i only get downvotes when I not check the site. There is a correlation with that.

Comment: When was the last time you received a downvote? I don't see any as far back as december.

Comment: This weekend, Kavin B I got 4 points down, two per day.

Comment: Correlation does not equal causation

Comment: @Kevin it might be deleted posts where the OP suggested an edit.

Comment: @Patrice I've said that quote to a few people in the last few weeks (offline) and they looked at me like I was crazy

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yeah...... we are in the era of "3 data points = undeniable proof" unfortunately :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### No.

There are no automatic changes to your reputation from merely visiting the site, nor are you penalized in any way for not visiting.

The only thing that your visiting the site affects are the Enthusiast and Fanatic [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), awarded for visiting the site each day for 30, and 100, consecutive days, respectively.

Whatever correlation you're seeing between not visiting the site and getting downvotes is merely spurious. It does not exist in reality. Votes on posts continue whether you are logged into the site or not, and low-quality posts are often downvoted.

It may simply be that it takes a couple of days for the experts in your tags to find and read your posts, so the downvotes come a day or two *after* your answers are posted, rather than immediately.

---

**Digging into [your reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670134/sirandy?tab=reputation&sort=time)**, it looks like you're not actually getting downvotes. Rather, **what's happening is that posts where you've suggested an edit are getting *deleted***. [Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18942999); [this is another example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22360889). In some cases, the questions you've edited are getting automatically deleted by system clean-up processes. In other cases, they are being manually deleted by moderators, or even the user who originally asked the question.

When you suggest an edit to a post, and that edit gets approved, you earn +2 reputation. We award this reputation in recognition of your *positive* contribution to the site—improving a post. However, when the post you've edited is deleted, you lose the reputation that you had gained. This is because you have no longer made a positive contribution to the site. The thing you edited to improve is now no longer visible, so edits to it are not valuable.

I see this happening for two questions 2 days ago (April 13), one question on March 16, one question on March 9, one question on March 5, and so on. The events show up as "removed", rather than "downvote".

There's not much that can be done about this, and it is *still* not correlated to your logging into the site. The posts that you had edited would still be deleted whether you had logged in or not.

The only thing you can do is try and focus your edits on useful questions that aren't likely to be deleted. Sometimes it's obvious, like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22456749) that the question is not going to stick around. Other times, [your edits are good](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18942999) and there's [no way to know that the question will eventually get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19392294).

Comment: Yeah, I got that badge. But this couldn't be a bug? Or how can I check that? Maybe there are a process that I have on pending status that is affecting my reputation.

Comment: There are no such processes. It cannot be a bug. The way to audit your reputation history is described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history).

Comment: I'm agree with the recent questions/answers, but my answers have more than 3 months

Comment: You need to stop and re-read what Cody wrote, he explained it completely. That link to your reputation history literally shows you the activity of your account from start to end.

Answer (score 1):

The score you get on questions or answers transcend your activity or availability on the site, so if others see them and feel that they aren't of quality, they may be downvoted.

The best thing you can do is to look at your questions and answers, be sure that they're clear and concise, and hope that others who look at them believe that they *are* of quality and are worthy of an upvote.