# How does changing a vote affect vote based reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

I understand perfectly how upvoting a question or answer affects the score of the beneficiary, and how downvoting the same affects the target and one's self.
However, I don't know how changing your vote affects the reputations in play.

**For example**,

- I recently removed an upvote on an answer, because I came to know it as faulty, whereas I assumed it to work earlier.
- Alternatively, I have also downvoted a question before and suggested edits based on the incoherent language used in the question. Later the question was more well formed and I changed the downvote to an upvote.

What are the reputation changes at play here?

Comment: There is no mistery. If you remove a vote, you remove the reputation effect of that vote. If you vote opposite of the way you voted in the past, it's as if you first removed the vote, and then voted again (and the corresponding reputation effect is applied).

Comment: The answers here are much more direct, but all that information and more can be found in the [reputation audit guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653/7795130).

Comment: Ok yeah, that guide covers everything :). Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a vote is removed reputation will be recalculated as if that vote were never cast in the first place.  In other words, you can pretend that you have a time machine and went back and prevented the vote from ever being cast, for the purposes of determining what the reputation should be of everyone involved.

It's worth noting that this is different than simply making a reputation change that is the negated version of the original change whenever the reputation cap is involved.  If the original vote was cast on a day where the recipient was rep capped, then "that vote not having been cast" might not result in a change in reputation.  Likewise, if it results in their reputation going up, it won't be calculated in the 200 rep that can be earned on the day the vote is reversed, because it's treated as reputation that simply wasn't lost back when the original vote was cast.

Answer (score 1):

Upvoting and downvoting only takes into account the final decision. When you change your decision, the prior voting is undone.

When you change from down to up, the -2 reputation loss is undone and a +5/+10 is added.

When you remove an upvote, the +5/+10 reputation won is undone.