# Stack Overflow Reputation Heat-Map Feature

Tags: feature-request, user-experience

One of the greatest things in my opinion in the very good UI from GitHub is the heatmap.

It is such a nice tool to visualize your activity.

[image: Heat Map GitHub]

At a glance you can recognize trends and you can see how much activity you had on the last days / months.

I would really like to see this in Stack Overflow.

At the moment when you would like to check a users reputation.(I am sometimes do this at the top users and been fascinated by values of 500+ rep a day.) you have this bar chart which gives you an overview.
But if you would like to see instead of only the last 30 days, another month for example, this is not possible.(Or I just don't find it).

Also the feature with selecting an area feels really clunky.

[image: Bar Chart]
[image]

Or you have to click through lists of activity data like this.

[image: Current Activity Situation]

A heatmap could do this in a much better way so you can get rid off the context to clicking on "Reputation" and then click through the pages. Instead only display the heatmap in the profile.

The Stack Overflow heatmap would show the earned rep a day as indicator for the activity.
The color coding could be in Orange / White like the colors of Stack Overflow.

Here is an example color coding for the days activity in the heatmap

- 0 -> grey
- 1 - 49 -> yellow
- 50 - 99 -> darker yelow
- 100 - 149 -> light orange
- 150 - 199 -> middle orange
- 200 + -> dark orange

Comment: I wouldn't say "reputation" is a full measure of *activity*, but are you aware there's already a graph of reputation - eg: https://stackoverflow.com/users/14747039/alex?tab=reputation&sort=graph ?

Comment: I should add this to my feature-request. Yes I know there is a graph but in my opinion I still think the heatmap will do a better job then the bar chart

Comment: Hmm, this might make it look like I have no life...

Comment: Is "activity" purely about rep gained? What about other non-rep-gaining "activities" like editing posts, helping in the review queues, participating on meta (where there's no rep)? Also, some users earn rep even when they're not anymore active on the site... not sure if those should still show up in the heatmap as "active".

Comment: @GinoMempin for editing posts you earn rep.
But a good point with non active users. Probably you have to disinguish between activity and reputation and this is just a Reputation heatmap.

Comment: When you reach 2k or have gained 1000 rep from edits, you stop earning rep from edits.

Comment: @GinoMempin okay didn't know this

Comment: @Alex what color code do you suggest for -ve rep?  ;)

Comment: @Yatin not red. That is to similar to orange :D

Comment: I would love having this feature. We already have a heat map in the form of the calendar but it just tracks if I have logged in on the site or not. Also it is not publicly visible.

Comment: @GinoMempin Except tag wiki and tag excerpt edits.

Comment: Related: [Add option to download reputation data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391338/1364007) if you want to implement this yourself.

Comment: here on SO my chart would be overwhelmingly positive, with passive rep gained nearly every day, however my chart on MSE would be overwhelmingly negative due to no passive rep gain and rep lost nearly daily on downvotes, but I'm far more "active" on MSE than SO. the charts are the opposite of an activity chart in my case. IMO an entirely new feature that actually tracks activity (not rep) would be better/more positive.

Comment: Disagree. This would emphasize the "game" more than the "product".

Comment: Additionally receiving downvotes would show up as a "negative" on the suggested chart as well, which I think would be easily misunderstood in a chart style that is generally used to show activity, not points gained/lost.

Comment: @KevinB I agree that it is not the best to show activity. But I think to show earned reputation it is a good choice and better than the bar chart.
In my opinion color coding the negative Reputation wouldn't been missunderstood. 
For sure you have to use complementary colors

Comment: there is no no need for that thing at all

Comment: Well, unpopular, but I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Old answer:

Sadly with the [new changes to the profile page to make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/598066), the calendar feature has been removed; because, and I quote, *"it’s a potentially toxic metric"*.

On [subsequent inquiry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive#comment1228253_368285) by [hkotsubo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/401803/hkotsubo):

> Why is the consecutive visit calendar potentially toxic?

[Aaron Shekey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/355163/aaron-shekey) - staff member and product designer at Stack Overflow  (who used to work at GitHub) - [replied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive#comment1228259_368285) by saying:

> @hkotsubo I don't personally want to incentivize consecutive visits or streaks. For some, they can lead to burnout and compulsive behavior. There has been quite a bit of similar discourse around GitHub's contribution graphs. While I'm proud of my contributions and streaks that occur naturally, I don't think it's something we should display outwardly.

So, as much as I hate to say this, this feature is highly unlikely to ever be implemented

---

New answer:

**The calendar feature is back!**

[image: The calendar feature is back]

So, there is still hope for a reputation heat map :)

Comment: It would be a shame if Stack was to keep any features that resembled gamification..

Comment: There is a balance there. Without addiction, Stack Overflow wouldn't exist (would be much closer to Quora's and Yahoo Answers' fate. The death of Usenet was not an accident).