# How can someone have a 7,000+ reputation drop?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-history

I was looking at this page: [Users > Reputation > Year > page 340,861](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=340860&tab=reputation&filter=year)  <sub><sup><sub><sup>This page may have changed by now after new users join</sup></sub></sup></sub>

I noticed that there's some pretty hefty drops. 2 users actually have dropped over 7,000 rep this past year.

But there's something interesting about these two drops: They are different.

Type 1 - Magic Drop

- around April, [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8682794/pearly-spencer?tab=topactivity) dropped 7000+ pts immediately

Type 2 - Steady Decline

- [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1982032/showkey?tab=topactivity) on the other hand has been steadily declining ever since Jan 2020. (And now has dropped 7,000+ since then)

---

What's happening behind the scenes here?

Comment: The second user has been offering a stack of bounties so not much of a mystery in that one.

Comment: On the [first user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8682794/pearly-spencer?tab=reputation), look at April 1st and 2nd. One or more other users were removed. The rep change was possibly correction of voting fraud.

Comment: @Blastfurnace That sounds correct. Yeah -3500 was removed. (I wonder why it's recorded as -7000..)

Comment: Voting correction. Second one seems to just be a ton of bounties offered.

Comment: Side note: only the rep loss due to voting correction does not say anything about the user whose rep sunk.

Comment: Sometimes, moderators go through and clean out the sock drawer. This tends to cause drops in reputation for multiple people. No real reason to discuss this publicly. It's not a bug. If this were your account, you could see what happened by following [these instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history).

Comment: I remember recently one user's rep dropped significantly and they asked what happened - turned out some unrelated voting ring used that user's account to dump a lot of "See, I vote honestly on good content, not just my ring" votes on that user's content (the user had  high enough reputation so likely for the ring it was ok to blindly assume all they content was good and upvotes don't look suspicious). Indeed all that rep was gone as result of the cleanup...  I have no idea if that what happened to the user in question - just wanted to point out that rep drop != vote fraud by account owner.