# I don't have a lot of questions but because of that I can never comment?

Tags: discussion

I want to comment or vote and partake in Stack Overflow, but I have to ask 25 individual questions to even have enough "reputation" to comment or like or dislike?
Yes I've looked over reddit and other options but I really don't want to abuse the system just to be able to be a part of the community. I've been a developer for years now and have used Stack Overflow for years as well, but I finally need to start commenting for work's sake so I don't know what to do here.

Comment: "*but I have to ask 25 individual questions*". Where did you see this information? It's incorrect; the commenting privilege comes with [50 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In general, all privileges are reputation based, and the number of posts doesn't matter. Also, "*need to start commenting for work's sake*" seems odd. Why would you need to to be able to write comments or up/down vote on SO for work?

Comment: It's not "like" or "dislike". It's "This post was useful" or "not useful".

Comment: If you want more reputation, then I think learning a skill and using that to answer Questions is the easiest way to do it. It sounds like the hardest, but asking Questions is really much harder than it seems.

Comment: (hidden hint: look for bounty questions ,you get +10 per vote , +15 per "marked as answer" , and N (the bounty, might even be 100s or 1000s in rare cases ) for bountied questions "marked as answer", also note: once you gained 200 rep. in any of the network sites , the system grants you +100 on EVERY community to comment ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On a Q&A site, the principle valuable thing that we seek is "questions" or "answers".  Comments do not have as significant a value as others may believe, since their usage has largely strayed from the idea of asking for clarification from an OP to having full-blown engagements there instead.

Because *only* questions or answers are indexed, your comments cannot be found.  Because they cannot be *found*, no one coming from Google could possibly see them there to get value. I won't deny the contrapositive in that someone who comes through Google and sees valuable comments could benefit, but the argument is still more about comments in general - the thing that brought them here certainly wasn't the *comment*, which is my point.

So... either start asking good questions, or start putting together good answers.

Comment: What about editing? :)

Comment: The [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) is more specific about the (narrow) purpose of comments on SO.

Comment: I don't really place a whole lot of impetus on that.  I'd *really* rather that if someone were just getting started here that they *not* suddenly add more content to the edit review queues, @Scratte.

Comment: @Makoto Good point. And with the new extremely narrow view area of suggested edits, I'd speculate that not a lot of reviewers bothers with that now.

Comment: @Scratte It's pretty darn hard to gain reputation 2 points at a time. Trust me, I've tried. Especially since if the edited question/answer is deleted, you lose the reputation.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I think it depends on personality. Only once did I ever manage to post an Answer in less than 15 minutes. They usually take me at least an hour, often more. One took me two days to prepare. It only took 15 seconds to get a downvote on it though :D I cherish it.

Answer (score 9):

It isn't about the number of questions, it's about the number of *upvotes* ("likes" as you call them) a question/answer receives.  If you ask or answer a question, and someone finds it useful, they can upvote it and you will gain 10 reputation.  This can be one good question, or 500 questions and answers.  Once you gain 50 reputation (5 upvotes), you gain the ability to comment.  [There are also other ways to gain reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269654/8384089), but they might not all be accessible to you at this time.

Also, looking at your profile, I can see that even though you've had this account for a year
<del>(which isn't "years" like you claimed)</del><sup>1</sup>, other than this post (which is on meta anyway and doesn't affect the main site's reputation), the only time you actually did something was on January 12th, 2021.  And on that day, you only asked one question.

To get the privileges, you need to prove that you are:

- Not someone who will attempt to abuse Stack Overflow (there are *way* too many of those people)
- Knowledgeable about programming
- Willing to put in some effort into the community

Some privileges are harder to get than others, but you already have the most important privilege: asking and answering questions.  You also have the ability to comment on your own posts, and to gain further privileges than that, all you have to do is become a member of the community.

<sup>1</sup>As @Scratte pointed out to me in the comments, you could have been using Stack Overflow without an account.

Comment: I used Stack Overflow for years before I created an account. I suspect most of the people that uses Stack doesn't have an account. Until they decide to post something. This was also mentioned by [Makoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto) in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406037/i-dont-have-a-lot-of-questions-but-because-of-that-i-can-never-comment/406038?noredirect=1#comment831579_406037)

Comment: @Scratte You can't expect the system to grant you privileges because you viewed questions.