# Tag badge scores gained from votes are lost without change in reputation

Tags: support, voting, tag-score

I've been trying to get the [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) silver badge and I'm pretty sure I had a score of 281.

Yesterday, I noticed my score in [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) was reduced to 218 from the 281 that I had. There is absolutely no trace in the reputation tab and my reputation has not changed at all. I'm now far behind the silver badge and I don't even know how it happened.

How can I get the score back and figure out what happened? I've seen other posts concerning changes in reputation, but they don't apply to my case since there is no change in my reputation.

Comment: Posts get deleted each night, that might influence your tag score without leaving a trace in your reputation tab for you. Did you check your deleted answers?

Comment: The scores on my answers got reduced and none of my posts are deleted. @rene

Comment: Sounds like the Flutter tag was removed from some question(s). That will reduce your tag score but not your rep.

Comment: No. For instance, my top answer (which has the flutter tag) had 17 scores, the next one had 14 and so on. But now most of my answers scores are reduced. @VLAZ

Comment: Hmm, true. I just went through [your answers on non-Flutter questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A9902765+-%5Bflutter%5D) (currently 24, a short-ish list) and none of them have been edited recently at all.

Comment: @yivi something happened since Sunday: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1427508 not much makes sense

Comment: I did a manual(-ish) calculation: [Your Flutter answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a9902765%20%5bflutter%5d). On the first page, the scores total to `165` on the second `56`, on the third `3`. That is a total of `224`. So, the tag score seems appropriate (the current badge score is 221 but presumably is caching). Dunno what else could have happened. Perhaps there was an incorrect calculation earlier that totalled 281 but then after re-calculation got the 221 score.

Comment: @rene huh. Theory: were some question(s) deleted? I know that if a question is up for 60 days (or something like that) then deletion doesn't remove the rep. But perhaps it does drop the score from the calculation.

Comment: Ok, but that's the sum of the current scores on my answers. The problem is that the scores on a lot of my answers were higher. @VLAZ

Comment: Theory: Some questions (and hence answers) were turned into community wiki?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yeah, no. You would see that in the on-hover

Comment: Just to be 100% sure: you visited your [recent deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/9902765) and that page is empty?

Comment: @Mobina Definitely very strange. If the votes were dropped let's say, from users being deleted, I'd expect a rep adjustment. The query from rene does suggest that. The SEDE data gets updated on Sundays, so it's accurate as of last week. There's been something this week, then.

Comment: There's only one answer which I deleted immediately and had zero score. @rene

Comment: @rene just for completeness, I checked [the user's rep from last Sunday](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1427538) and it was `4926`. Now it's 5091 which seems fair for five day's worth. So, it really doesn't seem there was invalidated votes. Or maybe they were invalidated but the rep remained? Weird.

Comment: I am not sure if I can say stuff publicly but there have been some (for lack of a better word) miscreants who've been doing some mischief ... so over the past week CMs have been working on lots and lots of voting related escalations ... I don't see that you specifically have been affected (from what tools I have), but it might have been. I'll let a CM know about this.

Comment: Yep, your account was one of the few hundreds that got caught up in the crossfire.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thank you for the investigation. I just lost lots of reputations while there's no serial upvoting in my reputation history! What can be done now?

Comment: Hey @Mobina, there's kinda nothing that can be done. It's unfortunate that your account was targeted. The CMs manually went through and made sure that only the targeted votes were removed, so you can be sure that the legitimate reputation which you earned wasn't removed.

Comment: @BhargavRao I was inactive for about a year and when I decided to get back to participating in the community, first thing that I got was losing lots of scores on my old posts and when I reported it I got reputation loss instead of a fix. This is a serious drawback from participating on my side. I wish there could be more of an explanation for this. Anyways, thank you for following up the issue.

Comment: @Mobina, I know I can't say anything else to make the situation better, but I do hope that some random folks targeting you wouldn't be the reason why you stopped contributing. All I can say now is sorry that you got into this mess, and I do mean it.

Comment: There were a lot of users affected the same way you were, but if it's any consolation you were probably in the top 5 users affected the most.

Answer (score 36):

<sub>Because Bhargav Rao got lost on his way to the answer box, I'm going to promote his comments to a proper answer. Don't let this stop you from reading his comments directly on the question.</sub>

Basically, Mobina, you were the unfortunate victim of some voting shenanigans. As is our policy with targeted voting, we invalidated all of these votes, which caused your reputation to be corrected automatically by the system. You can see the record of this in [your reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9902765/mobina?tab=reputation&sort=time):

[image: On June 23, there is an event of "-750", due to "-760" from a "reversal: voting corrected" and a "+10" from an "upvote".]

(See also: [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history) on how to audit your reputation history.)

The invalidation took place on June 23rd, and it caused you to lose 760 reputation points. The reputation history shows this as a "reversal" event, noting that "voting [was] corrected". You also got an upvote on one of your answers on June 23rd, which netted you +10 reputation, so your total reputation net on June 23rd was a depressing –750. That's the date where you lost all of your rep.

Now, **we have absolutely no reason to believe that you were in any way complicit—or even *aware*—of having been targeted for votes. In fact, you were unfortunately not the only user who was targeted.** There were a fair number of other users who were caught up in this mess, and they all lost a lot of reputation on this same day.

Unfortunately, I cannot go into any more detail about the events that necessitated this vote invalidation. **About all I can say is that there was a particular user (or a small group of users) who were indiscriminately showering other users with votes for reasons unrelated to the quality of their posts.** That's just as unfair as if they've been targeting these people with revenge downvotes, and we had to reverse that. We take our reputation system seriously, because we know many of our users do, too. (Not to mention reputation is the basis for the conference of privileges on the site.)

There's nothing magical about the day June 23rd. That's just the day when a staff member (Community Manager) found the time to investigate the voting abnormalities in detail and push the appropriate buttons to invalidate the targeted votes. It could have been any other day. It *should* have been much sooner after the targeted votes occurred, but it wasn't. I'm sorry about that. There is a large backlog on targeted voting investigations and only a very small number of people who can handle these. They also need to be handled with extreme care, to avoid making mistakes, and that means they take even longer.

Furthermore, both from myself and on behalf of the entire moderator team, we are very sorry that you had to experience this. We're sorry that someone saw fit to abuse the voting system in this manner, targeting you with inappropriate upvotes, making you think that you were legitimately earning reputation. You *have*, of course, legitimately earned a lot of reputation—and we earnestly thank you for the contributions that you've made here to have earned that reputation.

When we invalidate votes, we make sure *only* to invalidate the targeted/fraudulent votes. We don't remove any legitimately-earned votes. What that means is, even though it looks like you lost a bunch of reputation, you didn't, really. All of your *earned reputation* is still there.

The best way to think about vote invalidations is really that we are fixing a bug. There was a bug in the system that was causing it to report an incorrect reputation score for your account. **We've fixed that bug, and the fix resulted in your reputation going down, because the bug was causing an over-reporting. You didn't "lose" anything; we aren't punishing you.** (If you were in trouble or believed to be guilty of engaging in vote fraud directly, we would have sent you a private message to this effect, and possibly even a temporary suspension.)

As Bhargav already said, we realize that seeing this kind of thing in your reputation history, and seeing the reputation number that you've been tracking so carefully take a precipitous fall, can be very jarring and discouraging. We're sorry about that. If we had handled this situation earlier, it would have reduced the scope of the fallout. But, we didn't, and now you and other users are having to pay the consequences. **Please don't let this discourage you from continuing to participate.**

Comment: Just to add to this great explanation: the user responsible has been suspended for a long time and they are still serving their time in the penalty box.

Comment: @Dharman Can I ask a maybe obvious question: what is the benefit of these kinds of shenanigans to the one performing them? Revenge downvotes I get. Voting circles I get. Upvoting your crush I get. But flood-upvoting dozens of strangers? People you don’t know and will never meet? People who can’t, even in principle, know it was you upvoting? Just … why? What’s in it for me?

Comment: @DanBron In this case I assume it was a personal agenda, but it could also be a fault of gamification. We have rankings for people with the most votes cast. You'd have to conduct an interview with people like this to know what went through their head.

Comment: @DanBron There seemed to be a very clear (altruistic) reason/pattern to these votes but it's not really something I feel like I should discuss. I understand and appreciate the intentions of this voting behavior but it greatly misunderstood our voting ethic, which is why I'm having to revert all of the votes now.

Comment: @Catija Interesting! Thanks for replying. Glad to hear the voting came from a good place, from the heart. But now I’ll be speculating all day on what these people have in common.

Comment: Well, we don't *know* that it came from a good place, @Dan... Catija is just assuming good intentions, which is our usual practice. It is entirely possible that the serial voter's intention was, in fact, to disrupt our voting system, and only shrouded it in a veil of plausibility. I would only endorse what Dharman said. It's nearly futile to speculate on the thought process of people who do this. Their reasons will never be known to us, unless we could interview them and ask them. And even then, they could lie.

Answer (score 24):

Please know that I echo the sentiments of both Cody and Bhargav - this is mostly here to  explain some of the technical reasons you saw this result.

I can understand your confusion and I apologize for it - unfortunately there was a reputation change as part of this, it just came separately from the score changes. While it now looks like the invalidation happened before your posting this question, it was retroactively dated to when the buttons were pushed to invalidate the votes rather than when the system actually removed them.

This is a side effect of one of the two primary ways we invalidate votes on user profiles. When we invalidate *all* of the votes between two users, a reputation recalculation is triggered and it's processed within an hour or so and generally all of the effects happen simultaneously. This is the normal way we invalidate votes in cases of targeted voting as *usually* all of the votes need to be removed.

We have an alternative way of invalidating votes selectively in cases where only some of the votes from one user to another are concerning and this process can take longer to fully recalculate - in fact, when I asked one of our devs about it, he found that this form of invalidation doesn’t include recalculating the reputation at all, so it would only get recalculated if something else triggers a full recalculation (like a post deletion).

There’s definitely room for improvement in this tool, both in this specific way and others. In fact, your question has brought this particular failing to our attention, which may be cold comfort, but we'll look into how we can improve the tool for CMs so that others aren't seeing this same odd behavior.

We avoid talking about the specifics of why votes were invalidated but please know that this was the result of a long investigation where it was determined that many, many votes were cast in a targeted way and there are many hundreds of users impacted by it. In an effort to minimize the impact, we’re limiting how many votes we invalidate by only removing those that were clearly targeted rather than removing all of the votes - which is what led to this confusion.

Please know that this doesn’t diminish your efforts here or in any way indicate that the posts themselves weren’t worthy of upvotes - I’m very sorry that you were caught in the middle of this.